# OneToOne relationship with shared primary key generates n+1 selects; any workaround?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Imagine 2 tables in a relational database, e.g. Person and Billing. There is a (non-mandatory) OneToOne association defined between these entities, and they share the Person primary key (i.e. PERSON_ID is defined in both Person and Billing, and it is a foreign key in the latter).

When doing a select on Person via a named query such as:

```
from Person p where p.id = :id
```

Hibernate/JPA generates two select queries, one on the Person table and another on the Billing table.

The example above is very simple and would not cause any performance issues, given the query returns only one result. Now, imagine that `Person` has `n` OneToOne relationships (all non-mandatory) with other entities (all sharing the `Person` primary key).

Correct me if I'm wrong, but running a `select` query on Person, returning `r` rows, would result in `(n+1)*r` selects being generated by Hibernate, even if the associations are *lazy*.

Is there a workaround for this potential performance disaster (other than not using a shared primary key at all)? Thank you for all your ideas.

Comment: I think you're looking for "eager fetching", but I don't know hibernate. Hope that helps someone with a real answer.

Comment: With eager fetching, the data from those OneToOne associations would always be loaded (it's not what I want). What I'm looking for is a way to cap the number of native selects generated by Hibernate, independent of the number of rows returned.

Comment: Eager fetching doesn't affect Hibernate queries. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463349

Comment: This is a common problem.. giiglr for "hibernate n+1 selects"

Comment: Thank you all for your responses/comments! I tried some of the suggestions posted here and also googled around a bit. My problem is not quite the same as the "Hibernate n+1 select"-issue. To put it simpler: if I execute a HQL query such as "from Person p where p.id = :id", I would expect Hibernate to only hit the Person table, even if it has an optional OneToOne association with the Billing table. Instead, it hits the Billing table too! I also found (https://www.hibernate.org/162.html) - a more detailed explanation. I guess I should stay away, as Pat suggested. Unless a workaround exists?

Comment: One-to-One associations in Hibernate are, in my opinion, broken. Noone agrees with me, though. The usual workaround for his brokenness is to use a Many-To-One association with a unique=true restriction on the "many" end. Dumb, but it usually works.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Imagine 2 tables in a relational database, e.g. Person and Billing. There is a (non-mandatory) OneToOne association defined between these entities,

Lazy fetching is conceptually not possible for non-mandatory OneToOne by default, Hibernate has to hit the database to know if the association is `null` or not. More details from this old wiki page:

> #### [Some explanations on lazy loading (one-to-one)](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Someexplanationsonlazyloadingone-to-one)
>
> [...]
>
> Now consider our class B has
>   one-to-one association to C
>
> ```
> class B {
>     private C cee;
>
>     public C getCee() {
>         return cee;
>     }
>
>     public void setCee(C cee) {
>         this.cee = cee;
>     }
> }
>
> class C {
>     // Not important really
> }
> ```
>
> Right after loading B, you may call
>   `getCee()` to obtain C. But look,
>   `getCee()` is a method of YOUR class
>   and Hibernate has no control over it.
>   Hibernate does not know when someone
>   is going to call `getCee()`. That
>   means Hibernate must put an
>   appropriate value into "`cee`"
>   property at the moment it loads B from
>   database.   If proxy is enabled for
>   `C`, Hibernate can put a C-proxy
>   object which is not loaded yet, but
>   will be loaded when someone uses it.
>   This gives lazy loading for
>   `one-to-one`.
>
> But now imagine your `B` object may or
>   may not have associated `C`
>   (`constrained="false"`). What should
>   `getCee()` return when specific `B`
>   does not have `C`? Null. But remember,
>   Hibernate must set correct value of
>   "cee" at the moment it set `B`
>   (because it does no know when someone
>   will call `getCee()`). Proxy does not
>   help here because proxy itself in
>   already non-null object.
>
> So the resume: **if your B->C mapping
>   is mandatory (`constrained=true`),
>   Hibernate will use proxy for C
>   resulting in lazy initialization. But
>   if you allow B without C, Hibernate
>   just HAS TO check presence of C at the
>   moment it loads B. But a SELECT to
>   check presence is just inefficient
>   because the same SELECT may not just
>   check presence, but load entire
>   object. So lazy loading goes away**.

So, not possible... by default.

> Is there a workaround for this potential performance disaster (other than not using a shared primary key at all)? Thank you for all your ideas.

The problem is not the shared primary key, with or without shared primary key, you'll get it, the problem is the **nullable** OneToOne.

**First option**: use bytecode instrumentation (see references to the documentation below) and *no-proxy* fetching:

```
@OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY )
@org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOne(org.hibernate.annotations.LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
```

**Second option**: Use a fake `ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`. That's probably the most simple solution (and to my knowledge, the recommended one). But I didn't test this with a shared PK though.

**Third option**: Eager load the Billing using a `join fetch`.

#### Related question

- [Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

#### References

- Hibernate Reference Guide

  - [19.1.3. Single-ended association proxies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-proxies)
  - [19.1.7. Using lazy property fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties)
- Old Hibernate FAQ

  - [How do I set up a 1-to-1 relationship as lazy?](http://web.archive.org/web/20071021233649/http://www.hibernate.org/117.html#A18)
- Hibernate Wiki

  - [Some explanations on lazy loading (one-to-one)](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/Someexplanationsonlazyloadingone-to-one)

Comment: Thanks for such a great answer! Unfortunately, I cannot verify all your suggestions directly, as I don't have access to that code anymore. From what I remember, we implemented option 3 you suggested (join fetch).

Comment: When might the `JOIN FETCH` option end up being slower than a bunch of `SELECT` statements for an `EAGER` relationship?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common performance issue with Hibernate (just search for "Hibernate n+1"). There are three options to avoiding n+1 queries:

- Batch size
- Subselect
- Do a LEFT JOIN in your query

These are covered in the Hibernate FAQs [here](https://www.hibernate.org/118.html#A23) and [here](https://www.hibernate.org/117.html#A30)

Answer (score 1):

**Stay away from hibernate's OneToOne mapping**

It is very broken and dangerous. You are one minor bug away from a database corruption problem.

http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2128

Comment: [HHH-2128](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-2128) is a user issue, not an Hibernate issue, the user is using an nonsensical mapping. Pure PEBKAC problem, not Hibernate related.

Comment: really? so plan on telling that to the CEO, when 1-1 mapping results in a corrupted db? Tools are supposed to prevent PEBKAC issues. But guess you have never been coding at 3am trying to hit deadlines.

Answer (score 0):

You could try "blind-guess optimization", which is good for "n+1 select problems".
Annotate you field (or getter) like this:

```
@org.hibernate.annotations.BatchSize(size = 10)
java.util.Set<Billing> bills =  new HashSet<Billing>();
```

Answer (score 0):

That "n+1" problem will only occur if you specify the relationship as as lazy or you explicitly indicate that you want hibernate to run a separate query.

Hibernate can fetch the relationship to Billing with an outer join on the select of Person, obviating the n+1 problem altogether. I think it is the fetch="XXX" indication in your hbm files.

Check out [A Short Primer On Fetching Strategies](https://www.hibernate.org/315.html)

Answer (score 0):

use optional =true with a one-to-one relationship like this to avoid the n+1 issue

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
```