# How can I make a JPA OneToOne relation lazy

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading, one-to-one

In this application we are developing, we noticed that a view was particularly slow. I profiled the view and noticed that there was one query executed by hibernate which took 10 seconds even if there only were two object in the database to fetch. All `OneToMany` and `ManyToMany` relations were lazy so that wasn't the problem. When inspecting the actual SQL being executed, I noticed that there were over 80 joins in the query.

Further inspecting the issue, I noticed that the problem was caused by the deep hierarchy of `OneToOne` and `ManyToOne` relations between entity classes. So, I thought, I'll just make them fetched lazy, that should solve the problem. But annotating either `@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` or `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` doesn't seem to work. Either I get an exception or then they are not actually replaced with a proxy object and thus being lazy.

Any ideas how I'll get this to work? Note that I do not use the `persistence.xml` to define relations or configuration details, everything is done in java code.

Answer (score 252, accepted):

First off, some clarifications to **KLE**'s answer:

1. Unconstrained (nullable) one-to-one association is the only one that can not be proxied without bytecode instrumentation. The reason for this is that owner entity MUST know whether association property should contain a proxy object or NULL and it can't determine that by looking at its base table's columns due to one-to-one normally being mapped via shared PK, so it has to be eagerly fetched anyway making proxy pointless. Here's a [more detailed](https://developer.jboss.org/docs/DOC-13960) explanation.
2. many-to-one associations (and one-to-many, obviously) do not suffer from this issue. Owner entity can easily check its own FK (and in case of one-to-many, empty collection proxy is created initially and populated on demand), so the association can be lazy.
3. Replacing one-to-one with one-to-many is pretty much never a good idea. You can replace it with unique many-to-one but there are other (possibly better) options.

[**Rob H.**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1444623/208273) has a valid point, however you may not be able to implement it depending on your model (e.g. if your one-to-one association *is* nullable).

Now, as far as original question goes:

A) `@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)` should work just fine. Are you sure it's not being overwritten in the query itself? It's possible to specify `join fetch` in HQL and / or explicitly set fetch mode via Criteria API which would take precedence over class annotation. If that's not the case and you're still having problems, please post your classes, query and resulting SQL for more to-the-point conversation.

B) `@OneToOne` is trickier. If it's definitely not nullable, go with Rob H.'s suggestion and specify it as such:

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

Otherwise, if you can change your database (add a foreign key column to owner table), do so  and map it as "joined":

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="other_entity_fk")
public OtherEntity getOther()
```

and in OtherEntity:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "other")
public OwnerEntity getOwner()
```

If you can't do that (and can't live with eager fetching) bytecode instrumentation is your only option. I have to agree with **CPerkins**, however - if you have **80!!!** joins due to eager OneToOne associations, you've got bigger problems then this :-)

Comment: Maybe there is another option, but I have not personally tested it: on non constrained side, use a `one-to-one` with a formula like `select other_entity.id from other_entity where id = other_entity.id`. Of course, this is not ideal for query performances.

Comment: optional = false, does not work for me. @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "fundSeries", optional = false)
 private FundSeriesDetailEntity fundSeriesDetail;

Comment: The idea is to put joinColumn on the owning side with Lazy, not on the side that has mappedBy

Comment: Sad it's 2023 and still facing this issue :(

Answer (score 25):

Unless you are using Bytecode Enhancement, you cannot fetch lazily the parent-side `@OneToOne` association.

However, most often, you don't even need the parent-side association if you use `@MapsId` on the child-side:

```
@Entity(name = "PostDetails")
@Table(name = "post_details")
public class PostDetails {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @Column(name = "created_on")
    private Date createdOn;
 
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;
 
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Post post;
 
    public PostDetails() {}
 
    public PostDetails(String createdBy) {
        createdOn = new Date();
        this.createdBy = createdBy;
    }
 
    //Getters and setters omitted for brevity
}
```

With `@MapsId`, the `id` property in the child table serves as both Primary Key and Foreign Key to the parent table Primary Key.

So, if you have a reference to the parent `Post` entity, you can easily fetch the child entity using the parent entity identifier:

```
PostDetails details = entityManager.find(
    PostDetails.class,
    post.getId()
);
```

This way, you won't have N+1 query issues that could be caused by the `mappedBy` `@OneToOne` association on the parent side.

Comment: this way we cannot anymore cascade operations from parent to child :/

Comment: For persist, it's just an extra persist call, for delete, you can usd DDL cascade.

Comment: With the @MapsId, the child cannot be null right? And the parent must have @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)?

Comment: The answer tells you shouldn't use the parent-side OneToOne mapping, so just  set it on the child side.

Answer (score 24):

To get lazy loading working on nullable one-to-one mappings you need to let hibernate do [compile time instrumentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties) and add a `@LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)` to the one-to-one relation.

Example Mapping:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)  
@JoinColumn(name="other_entity_fk")
@LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
public OtherEntity getOther()
```

Example Ant Build file extension (for doing the Hibernate compile time instrumentation):

```
<property name="src" value="/your/src/directory"/><!-- path of the source files --> 
<property name="libs" value="/your/libs/directory"/><!-- path of your libraries --> 
<property name="destination" value="/your/build/directory"/><!-- path of your build directory --> 

<fileset id="applibs" dir="${libs}"> 
  <include name="hibernate3.jar" /> 
  <!-- include any other libraries you'll need here --> 
</fileset> 

<target name="compile"> 
  <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${destination}" debug="yes"> 
    <classpath> 
      <fileset refid="applibs"/> 
    </classpath> 
  </javac> 
</target> 

<target name="instrument" depends="compile"> 
  <taskdef name="instrument" classname="org.hibernate.tool.instrument.javassist.InstrumentTask"> 
    <classpath> 
      <fileset refid="applibs"/> 
    </classpath> 
  </taskdef> 

  <instrument verbose="true"> 
    <fileset dir="${destination}"> 
      <!-- substitute the package where you keep your domain objs --> 
      <include name="/com/mycompany/domainobjects/*.class"/> 
    </fileset> 
  </instrument> 
</target>
```

Comment: Why `LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY` and not `LazyToOneOption.PROXY`?

Comment: This does not answer the "why", but this fact is asserted here too (towards the end of the "Typical mapping" section): https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/

Comment: This approach is deprecated since hibernate "6.2".

Answer (score 16):

Here's something that has been working for me (without instrumentation):

Instead of using `@OneToOne` on both sides, I use `@OneToMany` in the inverse part of the relationship (the one with `mappedBy`). That makes the property a collection (`List` in the example below), but I translate it into an item in the getter, making it transparent to the clients.

This setup works lazily, that is, the selects are only made when `getPrevious()` or `getNext()` are called - and only **one** select for each call.

#### The table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `TB_ISSUE` (
    `ID`            INT(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `NAME`          VARCHAR(255) NULL,
    `PREVIOUS`      DECIMAL(9,2) NULL
    CONSTRAINT `PK_ISSUE` PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
);
ALTER TABLE `TB_ISSUE` ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_ISSUE_ISSUE_PREVIOUS`
                 FOREIGN KEY (`PREVIOUS`) REFERENCES `TB_ISSUE` (`ID`);
```

#### The class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TB_ISSUE") 
public class Issue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Integer id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)  // one to one, as expected
    @JoinColumn(name="previous")
    private Issue previous;

    // use @OneToMany instead of @OneToOne to "fake" the lazy loading
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="previous", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    // notice the type isnt Issue, but a collection (that will have 0 or 1 items)
    private List<Issue> next;

    public Integer getId() { return id; }
    public String getName() { return name; }

    public Issue getPrevious() { return previous; }
    // in the getter, transform the collection into an Issue for the clients
    public Issue getNext() { return next.isEmpty() ? null : next.get(0); }

}
```

Comment: What a clever yet simple solution! Thanks a lot for sharing this idea! BTW in your example you only wrote a getter, do you think doing the same with a setter method could cause some syncing problems? This is how I tried implement it (given that I initialized my `@OneToMany` field with an empty collection thus it can never be `null`):
`public void setNext(Issue next) {`
`if (next == null) {`
`this.next.clear();`
`} else if (this.next.isEmpty()) {`
`this.next.add(next);`
`} else {`
`throw new IllegalArgumentException("Issue already has a next one");`
`}`
`}`

Comment: Following my previous comment: Maybe my setter method could replace the existing `next` issue when setting a new one instead of throwing an exception, but I was unsure if it would need to clear the relationship on the other side... Any thoughts about this would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 15):

The basic idea behing the XToOnes in Hibernate is that they are not lazy in most case.

One reason is that, when Hibernate have to decide to put a proxy (with the id) or a null,
**it has to look into the other table anyway** to join. The cost of accessing the other table in the database is significant, so it might as well fetch the data for that table at that moment (non-lazy behaviour), instead of fetching that in a later request that would require a second access to the same table.

**Edited: for details, please refer to ChssPly76 's answer**. This one is less accurate and detailed, it has nothing to offer. Thanks ChssPly76.

Comment: There are several things wrong here - I've provided another answer below with an explanation (too much stuff, won't fit into a comment)

Answer (score 7):

In native Hibernate XML mappings, you can accomplish this by declaring a [one-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html_single/#mapping-declaration-onetoone) mapping with the *constrained* attribute set to true. I am not sure what the Hibernate/JPA annotation equivalent of that is, and a quick search of the doc provided no answer, but hopefully that gives you a lead to go on.

Comment: +1 for a good suggestion; unfortunatelly it's not always applicable as domain model may actually require nullability. The proper way to map this via annotations is `@OneToOne(optional=false,fetch=FetchMode.LAZY)`

Comment: I tried this and saw no performance improvement.  I still saw many queries in the hibernate output via the debugger.

Answer (score 4):

As already perfectly explained by ChssPly76, Hibernate's proxies don't help with unconstrained (nullable) one-to-one associations, BUT there is a trick explained [here](http://justonjava.blogspot.it/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html) to avoid to set up instrumentation.  The idea is to fool Hibernate that the entity class which we want to use has been already instrumented: you instrument it manually in the source code.  It's easy!  I've implemented it with CGLib as bytecode provider and it works (ensure that you configure lazy="no-proxy" and fetch="select", not "join", in your HBM).

I think this is a good alternative to *real* (I mean automatic) instrumentation when you have just one one-to-one nullable relation that you want to make lazy.  The main drawback is that the solution depends on the bytecode provider you are using, so comment your class accurately because you could have to change the bytecode provider in the future; of course, you are also modifying your model bean for a technical reason and this is not fine.

Answer (score 4):

This question is quite old, but with Hibernate 5.1.10, there are some new better comfortable solution.

Lazy loading works except for the parent side of a @OneToOne association. This is because Hibernate has no other way of knowing whether to assign a null or a Proxy to this variable. More details you can find in [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

- You can activate lazy loading bytecode enhancement
- Or, you can just remove the parent side and use the client side with @MapsId as explained in the article above. This way, you will find that you don’t really need the parent side since the child shares the same id with the parent so you can easily fetch the child by knowing the parent id
  .

Answer (score 2):

For Kotlin devs: To allow Hibernate to inherit from the @Entity types that you want to be lazy-loadable they have to be inheritable/`open`, which they in Kotlin by default are not. To work around this issue we can make use of the [`all-open` compiler plugin](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#all-open-compiler-plugin) and instruct it to also handle the JPA annotations by adding this to our `build.gradle`:

```
allOpen {
   annotation("javax.persistence.Entity")
   annotation("javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass")
   annotation("javax.persistence.Embeddable")
}
```

If you are using Kotlin and Spring like me, you are most probably also using the [`kotlin-jpa`/`no-args`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#jpa-support) and [`kotlin-spring`/`all-open`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/compiler-plugins.html#spring-support) compiler plugins already. However, you will still need to add the above lines, as that combination of plugins neither makes such classes `open`.

Read the great [article of Léo Millon](https://medium.com/@millon.leo/are-you-sure-the-lazy-fetch-mode-is-configured-correctly-in-your-kotlin-hibernate-project-e75f072cdb5d) for further explanations.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been racking my head for a solid day until I found your answer and it solved my problem. I hadn't even imagined looking into that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Most efficient mapping of a one-to-one association
You can avoid all these problems and get rid of the foreign key column by using the same primary key value for both associated entities. You can do that by annotating the owning side of the association with @MapsId.

```
@Entity
public class Book {
 
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
 
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "book", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private Manuscript manuscript;
 
    ...
}


@Entity
public class Manuscript {
 
    @Id
    private Long id;
 
    @OneToOne
    @MapsId
    @JoinColumn(name = "id")
    private Book book;
 
    ...
}


Book b = em.find(Book.class, 100L);
Manuscript m = em.find(Manuscript.class, b.getId());
```

[More Detail click on this url](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-lazy-loading-one-to-one/)

Comment: You only avoid this problem if you make this a unidirectional relationship (as your link also states), which the above example is not. This also presents other problems, like not having access to the children from the parent or not being able to use cascades. Otherwise, this is basically a repost of what @Vlad_Mihalcea already posted.

Answer (score 0):

If the relation must not be bidirectional then an @ElementCollection might be easier than using a lazy One2Many collection.

Answer (score 0):

If the child entity is used readonly, then it's possible to simply **lie** and set `optional=false`.
Then ensure that every use of that mapped entity is preloaded via queries.

```
public class App {
  ...
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "app", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  private Attributes additional;
```

and

```
String sql = " ... FROM App a LEFT JOIN FETCH a.additional aa ...";
```

... maybe even persisting would work...