# Efficiently determining the IDs of entities referenced via OneToMany relationship

Tags: java, hibernate

Let's say I have a Hibernate entity that declares a `OneToMany` relationship to a different entity:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private List<OtherEntity> otherEntities = new LinkedList<OtherEntity>();

  [...]
}
```

When mapping `SomeEntity` to the corresponding DTO, all I need are the IDs that identify `OtherEntity` as primary key (i.e., I am not actually interested in `OtherEntity` instances).

Does Hibernate support this pattern, i.e., only retrieving the IDs of entities referenced via a `OneToMany` relationship?

I cannot influence how `SomeEntity` is retrieved (i.e., I have an existing `SomeEntity` instance retrieved within te scope of the current Hibernate session), but let's assume that lazy loading has not yet taken place, so just retrieving the child objects' IDs (rather than the complete objects) would actually yield a performance benefit.

Comment: do you want this inside the **SomeEntity** or a separate **List<OtherEntity>(Only IDs)** is fine?

Comment: Having it in SomeEntity would be preferable.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you only need the entities' ids and you want to be economical about it, when you get those entities from the database you should state in your query that you only want to get the ids of each entry, using projections, something like :

```
 SELECT Entity.id as entity FROM Entity WHERE ...
```

This will return an array of objects of the same type as Entity's id field type.

Answer (score 0):

You can try obtaining the primary key without accessing the entity itself (without `otherEntities.get(0).getId()`). To do this you can use the `PersistenceUnitUtil` class:

[PersistenceUnitUtil#getIdentifier(yourEntity)](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/index.html?overview-summary.html)

The `PersistenceUnitUtil` can be obtained from the `EntityManagerFactory`. So it could be something like:

```
EntityManager em = ...  
PersistenceUnitUtil = em.getEntityManagerFactory().getPersistenceUnitUtil();
```

Unfortunately, I'm not aware if this will prevent the entity loading from occuring. However, just accessing the `otherEntities` collection or even obtaining references to each entity will not make the instance to be loaded; you need to invoke a method on the fetched entity in order to be sure it will be loaded.

You also might consider creating a `@NamedQuery` and return only the `OtherEntity` ID's.

HTH!

Answer (score 0):

From hibernate reference, section 2.2.2.1.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#entity-mapping-property

Declare your columns as lazy initialized:

@Basic(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   private String getYourProperty() {
   }

You also need to disable proxies for your entity class and byte instrument it. There is an example here:

[Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below **HQL** as told in the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-select) to establish this.

```
session.createQuery(select new OtherEntity(oe.id) OtherEntity oe 
           where oe.parentSomeEntity.someId = :someId).list();//also set someId.
```

Add a constructor in `OtherEntity` to set the `id` also there should be a mapping to `SomeEntity` in `OtherEntity`.

This HQL will give you a `List<OtherEntity>` with only `id` set in the bean.