# Hibernate ORM: How to avoid fetching @OneToOne mapped objects?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have following entities:

Employee [@Id Long id, String name, @OneToOne Address branchAddress, @OneToOne Address homeAddress]

Address [@Id Long id, String street, String City, String zipcode, Country country]

Country [@Id Long id, String name, String currency, String isoCode]

My problem is when I try to load Employee, most of the time I don't want address. Fetching address fetches address and subsequenty country. These are extra queries that are executed everytime I load employee.

I have tried making @OneToOne(FetchType.LAZY) but doesn't work, it still pulls unneeded information.

How can i avoid fetching composite objects?

I would like the end result to not contain Address objects, Since it is needed once in 20 scenarios I can fetch them separately.

Any ideas, how to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If our oneToOne value is not nullable, you can achieve lazy loading by adding `optional=false` : 
@OneToOne(optional=false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY).

It is perfectly [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1444227/233495) .