# What's the JPA equivalent of the Hibernate @LazyToOne annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, lazy-loading

I am currently using the Hibernate `@LazyToOne` annotation.

Since I'm switching from  Hibernate to JPA, I'd like to know whether `@LazyToOne` is available in JPA, or is there any other annotation that provides the same functionality in JPA?

Comment: @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY) like this.

Answer (score 4):

### `@LazyToOne` and `LazyToOneOption`

The legacy `@LazyToOne` annotation provides the following options:

- `FALSE`
- `PROXY`
- `NO_PROXY`

[image: LazyToOne annotation]

### `LazyToOneOption.FALSE`

The `FALSE` option is equivalent to the JPA [`FetchType.EAGER`](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) annotation, so it should be avoided as it can cause serious performance issues.

### `LazyToOneOption.PROXY`

The `PROXY` option is equivalent to the JPA [`FetchType.LAZY`] strategy. However, you should prefer using the `fetch` attribute of the JPA [`@OneToOne`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) or [`@ManyToOne`](https://vladmihalcea.com/manytoone-jpa-hibernate/) associations instead.

### `LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY`

This strategy is useful when using the `@OneToOne` association on the parent side.

So, assuming you have the following `Post` and `PostDetails` entities:

[image: Post and PostDetails entities]

If the `Post` maps the parent-side of this one-to-one table relationship:

```
@OneToOne(
    mappedBy = "post",
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
private PostDetails details;
```

Even if the association uses the `FetchType.LAZY` strategy, we can see that if we want to fetch the `Post` entity:

```
Post post = doInJPA(entityManager -> {
    return entityManager.find(Post.class, 1L);
});
```

The `PostDetails` is going to be fetched eagerly:

```
SELECT p.id AS id1_0_0_,
       p.title AS title2_0_0_
FROM post p
WHERE p.id = 1
 
SELECT pd.id AS id1_1_0_,
       pd.created_by AS created_2_1_0_,
       pd.created_on AS created_3_1_0_
FROM post_details pd
WHERE pd.id = 1
```

This is because Hibernate doesn't know how to initialize the `details` property since it needs to decide whether to use `null` or a Proxy, and the only way to find that out is to issue a SELECT query.

So, to fix this issue, we need to things:

- enable lazy fetching bytecode enhancement
- use the `NO_PROXY` strategy

To enable lazy loading bytecode enhancement, we can use this Hibernate Maven plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And, we also need to use the `NO_PROXY` strategy:

```
@OneToOne(
    mappedBy = "post",
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL
)
@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
private PostDetails details;
```

With this change in place, the parent-side `@OneToOne` association is going to be fetched lazily.

Comment: But according to docs, using FALSE will eagerly load the association and using NO_PROXY will give back the real object loaded when a reference is requested. But doesn't eager-loading mean giving the real object back instead of proxy? So, what's the difference between these two?

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
```

More details in this question:
[Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

Comment: This is not the same as `@LazyToOne` unless you also set `optional=true`, Nullable one-to-one refernces are always eager

Comment: Did you mean optional=false?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `jpql`, like:

```
User user = em.createQuery("SELECT NEW com.model.User(u.id, u.name, u.password)
    FROM User u WHERE u.id = :id", User.class)
        .setParameter("id", 1L)
        .gerSingleResult();`
```

It may solve your problem. But, you have to remember to write the default constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It should be

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=false)
```

Found on this forum: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2388783

The reason, I guess, is that the only way for JPA to know if an attribute has already been fetched is to check it has a value, but if null is a valid value then there's no way to tell. Hence optional attributes are always fetched regardless.