# Hibernate ManyToOne FetchType.LAZY is not working?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, lazy-loading

I am using spring 4.1.4.RELEASE + hibernate 4.3.6.Final, here is my entity code:

```
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
}


public class MarketInfo extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "market_id", unique = true, length = 15)
    private String marketId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "market")
    private List<MarketChannelGroup> channelGroups;

    public List<MarketChannelGroup> getChannelGroups() {
        return channelGroups;
    }

    public void setChannelGroups(List<MarketChannelGroup> channelGroups) {
        this.channelGroups = channelGroups;
    }

...
}

public class MarketChannelGroup extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "market_id", referencedColumnName = "market_id")
    private MarketInfo market;
...
}
```

From my test I can see the channelGroups in MarketInfo is working fine (if I don't call getChannelGroups(), then channelGroups is null), however if I call getChannelGroups(), the MarketInfo inside each MarketChannelGroup gets fetched, while this should not happen since market's fetch mode is FetchType.LAZY.

From console I do see the following hibernate log when I call its getter:

```
Hibernate: select channelgro0_.market_id as market_i5_12_1_, channelgro0_.id as id1_9_1_, channelgro0_.id as id1_9_0_, channelgro0_.channel_group_id as channel_2_9_0_, channelgro0_.channel_group_name as channel_3_9_0_, channelgro0_.channel_group_type as channel_4_9_0_, channelgro0_.market_id as market_i5_9_0_ from market_channel_group channelgro0_ where channelgro0_.market_id=?
Hibernate: select marketinfo0_.id as id1_12_0_, marketinfo0_.enable_flag as enable_f2_12_0_, marketinfo0_.enable_time as enable_t3_12_0_, marketinfo0_.market_id as market_i4_12_0_, marketinfo0_.market_name as market_n5_12_0_, marketinfo0_.stb_count as stb_coun6_12_0_ from market_info marketinfo0_ where marketinfo0_.market_id=?
Hibernate: select marketinfo0_.id as id1_12_0_, marketinfo0_.enable_flag as enable_f2_12_0_, marketinfo0_.enable_time as enable_t3_12_0_, marketinfo0_.market_id as market_i4_12_0_, marketinfo0_.market_name as market_n5_12_0_, marketinfo0_.stb_count as stb_coun6_12_0_ from market_info marketinfo0_ where marketinfo0_.market_id=?
Hibernate: select marketinfo0_.id as id1_12_0_, marketinfo0_.enable_flag as enable_f2_12_0_, marketinfo0_.enable_time as enable_t3_12_0_, marketinfo0_.market_id as market_i4_12_0_, marketinfo0_.market_name as market_n5_12_0_, marketinfo0_.stb_count as stb_coun6_12_0_ from market_info marketinfo0_ where marketinfo0_.market_id=?
```

could anyone help?

**UPDATE**

*there is no optional method for ManyToOne annotation, so the solution in OneToOne doesn't work for my case.*

Comment: Try with `optional=false` in your ManyToOne association. Refer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17987718/1282369

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate: one-to-one lazy loading, optional = false](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987638/hibernate-one-to-one-lazy-loading-optional-false)

Comment: @tsatiz, optional=false is not recognized by hibernate here, only OneToOne has that optional method.

Comment: ok, can you try to create a field for market_id column and refer the logical name in the relation. something like
`private int marketId;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "marketId", referencedColumnName = "market_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private MarketInfo market;
`

Comment: about the optional=false option, hibernate 5 has it for `@ManyToOne`. I didn't check which version you are using. Sorry about that.

Comment: did u solve it?

Comment: @AnkitBansal, no, I didn't, I finally found hibernate is not so flexible, and I decided not to use it anymore.

Comment: 1 moment, "lazy" means: it (the list of MarketChannelGroups) is not loaded, when you load one `MarketInfo` ...but of course it *should* load when you call `getChannelGroups()` (in a transactional context) ...that's how lazy works....what would you expect to return(, when you call `getChannelGroups()`...and no db select takes place..)?

Answer (score 0):

Move the @OneToMany annotation from the declaration to the getter method, like this:

```
private List<MarketChannelGroup> channelGroups;

@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "market")
public List<MarketChannelGroup> getChannelGroups() {
    return channelGroups;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How is your configuration archive? Look if you are using the filter **OpenEntityManagerInViewFilter**. If  you are using it, always that you call the method Lazy **getChannelGroups()** the hibernate will get fetch inside each element.

Comment: There is no filter enabled in my hibernate setting.

Answer (score 0):

You have to take oneToMany annotation to getter if @id is on the getter. Lazy works but if you or some framework get the lazy property in that transction the get method fire the select.