# Hibernate OneToMany FetchType.LAZY is not working unless accessing the collection?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, one-to-many

I am using spring 4.1.4.RELEASE + hibernate 4.3.6.Final, here is my entity code:

```
public class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
}

public class MarketInfo extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "market_id", unique = true, length = 15)
    private String marketId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "market")
    private List<MarketChannelGroup> channelGroups;

    public List<MarketChannelGroup> getChannelGroups() {
        return channelGroups;
    }

    public void setChannelGroups(List<MarketChannelGroup> channelGroups) {
        this.channelGroups = channelGroups;
    }

...
}

public class MarketChannelGroup extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private int id;


    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "market_id", referencedColumnName = "market_id")
    private MarketInfo market;
...
}
```

I have a MarketInfo, I expect that when I call its getChannelGroups() method, it will return List, however I can see HQL query is not triggered in this case, it seems that we must access some item inside that List to trigger the HQL query, otherwise, MarketInfo's channelGroups is null.

Case 1:

```
System.out.println(market.getChannelGroups()); // this is working, market's channelGroups is not empty. HQL query is triggered.

// here market's channelGroups is not empty
```

Case 2:

```
market.getChannelGroups(); // this is not working, market's channelGroups is still empty.HQL query is not triggered.

// here market's channelGroups is empty
```

Case 3:

```
market.getIndexes().get(0).getDate(); // this is working, market's channelGroups is not empty. HQL query is triggered.

// here market's channelGroups is not empty
```

Could anyone help explain?

Comment: I don't understand your example. What do you mean by `market.getChannelGroups()` is working and not working?

Comment: @ujulu, please check two cases above.

Comment: this can be helpfull (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39748211/hibernate-manytoone-fetchtype-lazy-is-not-working?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> market.getChannelGroups(); // this is not working, market's channelGroups is still empty.

The reason why this is happening might be the `market.getChannelGroups()` call is returning a **proxy** because of the lazy loading. The actual loading will happen when you call a method on the returned object which in this case is channel groups collection.
So to trigger the loading of the entities into the collection you have to call the following, for example:

```
market.getChannelGroups().size();
```

Now why is the following call working?

```
System.out.println(market.getChannelGroups());
```

The reason will be clear if you understand how `System.out.println()` is working, namely, it is calling the `toString()` method on the passed in object which in this case is equivalent to the following:

```
System.out.println(market.getChannelGroups().toString());
```

Here is the JavaDoc for the `println(Object)` method:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

Comment: market.getChannelGroups().size(); is not working, it seems we must access some item inside the list. is this normal behavior? can we have some other solution rather than force calling some code just for triggering the lazy loading?

Comment: Lazy loading is meant that objects should not be loaded until they are really needed. If you don't want this behavior **and if you don't have huge number of elements in your collection** you can change `LAZY` to `EAGER` so that the provider loads the objects in the collection eagerly.

Comment: ok, thanks, in fact "market.getChannelGroups().size();" is working now.