# n+1 issue in one to one relation with Lazy Loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

My Question is when an null ability  occur in one to one relation even my child class Primary Key same like parent class Primary Key So when Insert     @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn on one to one relation in Insertion I have seen  below Link Issue [not-null property references a null or transient value in one to one relation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273260/org-hibernate-propertyvalueexception-not-null-property-references-a-null-or-tra)

and when i Remove this tag n+1 issue resolved ...so how can i resolved it Please Help

```
private SiteSecurity siteSecurity;
private SiteDetails details;
private SiteAvr avr;
private SiteRectifier rectifier;

@OneToOne( fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "site")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
```

in Parent Class Fields regarding one to one relations

```
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "site"))
@Id
@GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Site getSite() {
    return site;
}

public void setSite(Site site) {
    this.site = site;
}
```

this is child class so how can i resolved both issue not null and n+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply set `optional=true` in your `OneToOne` relationship like:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
public Site getSite() {
    return site;
}
```

Comment: OneToOne default true this answer is wrong

Answer (score 0):

To avoid the n+1 Problem ensure the one to one relationship in sync with the other table if Site Table has a row so another one to one relation table has a row against them and this annotation @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn is on them...

In My case, this strategy will work to avoid the n+1 problem

Please Got through this Like is also Briefly elaborate the One to One Relation [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987638/hibernate-one-to-one-lazy-loading-optional-false?noredirect=1&lq=1)