# Annotation @BatchSize not working

Tags: hibernate, jpa, annotations, one-to-one, select-n-plus-1

I have 3 JPA classes an `Account` that includes a single `Address` which has a `City` Object

```
public class Account implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields
private Address address;


//Setters and getters for other fields

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "account")
public Address getAccountAddress() {
    return this.address;
}

public void setAccountAddress(Address address) {
    this.address = address;
}
```

---

```
public class Address implements java.io.Serializable {

// Fields
private City city;

//Setters and getters for other fields

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "CityId", nullable = false)
public City getCity() {
    return this.city;
}
```

I wanted to solve the N+1 select problem, I tried using @BatchSize above the classes, but it didn't stop the N+1 calls to the Database, therefore I had to set the batchSize in my `persistence.xml`

```
 <property name="hibernate.default_batch_fetch_size" value="50" />
 <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="50" />
```

Now It works except for one entity which is `Address`, so I get one SQL select for City and for Account but I still get N SQL select for Address. I've noticed that the only difference is that the relationship between Account and Address is one-to-one

My questions are:

1. Can the relation one-to-one be the reason I'm still getting N select on the table Address? and why?
2. Why isn't the Annotation working (Why did I have to set it in `persistence.xml`), is there some setting that should be done for the annotation to be effective ?

Answer (score 2):

1. Hibernate nullable (optional) OneToOne cannot be lazy. There's lot of articles about this problem and a few workarounds. E.g. read this [Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy/1445694)
2. Above which classes have you put `@BatchSize`? You should put it above the `City` class. Also try `@BatchSize` above the method `getCity()`;

Comment: FYI, adding `@BatchSize` on `getCity()` or `getAccountAddress()` (or the equivalent of it in my system) doesn't seem to work.