# Lazy loading in One to One Mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, lazy-loading

I have a data model class Account.In Account class I have one one property Contact(Custom class) and this is having one to one mapping.So I am using like this in Account class:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "account", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
public Contact getContact() {
        return contact;
    }
```

After doing this contact property is not lazy loading.I have tried `optional=false` and `@LazyToOne (LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)`.But no luck.
Could you please help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

Answer (score 1):

Lazy Loading with OneToOne behaves little differently.

[This](http://ankursinghal86.blogspot.in/2014/07/one-to-one-and-lazy-vs-eager-loading.html) might help you out. Just follow the post.

Comment: Ankur,I have already tried optional=false and @LazyToOne (LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY).But still not working.

Comment: @Geek I have mentioned in my above post, try adding `@JoinColumn` for your `OneToOne` mapping

Comment: @Geek If the above solved your problem, accept the answer to increase your acceptance rating.