# Why does JPA use FetchType EAGER by default for the @ManyToOne relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I came to notice that the default `FetchType` for the `@ManyToOne` mapping is `EAGER` in JPA and Hibernate, whereas for the `@OneToMany` mapping, the default `FetchType` is `LAZY`.

What is the specific reason behind this?

Answer (score 41):

From the **JPA 2.0 spe**c, the defaults are like so:

```
OneToMany: LAZY
ManyToOne: EAGER
ManyToMany: LAZY
OneToOne: EAGER
```

And in **hibernate, all is Lazy**

From Hibernate Docs,

> By default, Hibernate uses lazy select fetching for collections and
>   lazy proxy fetching for single-valued associations. These defaults
>   make sense for most associations in the majority of applications.

To answer your question, Hibernate is an implementation of the JPA standard. Hibernate has its own quirks of operation, but as per the Hibernate docs

```
By default, Hibernate uses lazy select fetching for collections and lazy proxy fetching for single-valued associations. These defaults make sense for most associations in the majority of applications.
```

So Hibernate will always load any object using a lazy fetching strategy, no matter what type of relationship you have declared.

**JPA Spec** assumes that in general most of the applications will require the singleton relations by default be eager, whereas multi value relations by default be lazy.

Refer [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazy) for more

Comment: Can you provide the link to the documentation from where you have copied the quoted text?

Comment: @RAS refer [this](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazy)

Comment: "So Hibernate will always load any object using a lazy fetching strategy, no matter what type of relationship you have declared." Incorrect as Hibernate is loading using EAGER strategy in code where I have used ManyToOne mapping. And also in hibernate source default Fetch type is set to EAGER.

Comment: @vatsalmevada are you using Hibernate or JPA

Comment: Sorry I am using JPA annotations.. If I use hibernate mapping files then it will do LAZY fetch by default?

Comment: @vatsalmevada yes that is what i explained in my answer, JPA and Hibernate behaves differently. JPA is just the implementation

Comment: i.e Hibernate doesn't follow the JPA spec then? aka incompatibility.

Comment: what about A -> B -> C. if I get C, B will be eager in C object. will that B contains A too? or only eager upto one level?

Answer (score 22):

### JPA gotcha

The reason for setting those to EAGER was because the early JPA 1.0 designers assumed that enforcing JPA implementations to support dynamically initializing Proxies would be a very strong requirement. However, since without Proxies, performance would suffer tremendously, all providers support LAZY associations.

### Avoid `FetchType.EAGER`

Using the default EAGER fetching strategy for `@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` associations is [a terrible idea](http://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/) as you can easily end up with [N+1 query issues](https://vladmihalcea.com/n-plus-1-query-problem/).

When using Hibernate, once an association is set to `FetchType.EAGER`, you can no longer fetch it lazily at query time. So, you are always going to fetch that relationship whether the current business use case needs it or not.

### Use `FetchType.LAZY` by default

So, you are better off using `FetchType.LAZY` by default for all associations.

Unlike `FetchType.EAGER`, a `FetchType.LAZY` relationship can be fetched eagerly at query time using a `JOIN FETCH` clause.

The only thing you need to be aware of is that you need to fetch a lazy association in the context of the currently running Persistence Context if you need to access the association after the JPA `EntityManager` is closed. Otherwise, you are going to get a [`LazyInitializationException`](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-handle-the-lazyinitializationexception/)

Comment: It is also worth noting that @OneToOne in Hibernate is always Eager unless the association is marked as optional=false. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy

Comment: except that many JPA providers don't use "proxies" for single-valued relations.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at it carefully, you will find that if the relationship ends with `Many` keyword i.e. `OneToMany`, `ManyToMany`, it is Lazy. If it ends with `One` i.e. `ManyToOne`, `OneToOne`, it is Eager. So the thing is if you have to load just one object it will fetch it very fast. But if it is loading many objects it will take a lot of time. So, to stop that loading time by default they should have set it to the Lazy loading.

Answer (score 0):

if you use lazyfetch in ManyToOne, you have to use join when you do a query which gets all the models in the many side