# I don't now why occur N+1 Problem using QueryDSL

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I used Spring Boot and QueryDSL.

When called `findAllByWriterGroupByClient` method in `ClientMemoRepositoryImpl.java`, [generated query 1] generated once and [generated query 2] generated several times.

Additionally, when read result of this query as Tuple in `ClientMemoServiceImpl.java`, [generated query 3] is generated many times.

---

- ClientMemoRepositoryImpl.java

```
@Override
public List<Tuple> findAllByWriterGroupByClient(String searchKeyword, Long writerId, boolean hasAdminRole) {
    QClientMemo qClientMemo1 = new QClientMemo("cm1");
    QClientMemo qClientMemo2 = new QClientMemo("cm2");

    JPAQuery<Tuple> memoDtoJPAQuery = qf.select(
                    JPAExpressions.selectFrom(qClientMemo1)
                            .where(qClientMemo1.clientId.eq(qClientMemo.clientId).and(
                                            qClientMemo1.createdDate.eq(
                                                    JPAExpressions
                                                            .select(qClientMemo2.createdDate.max())
                                                            .from(qClientMemo2)
                                                            .where(qClientMemo2.clientId.eq(qClientMemo.clientId))
                                            )
                                    )
                            ),
                    new CaseBuilder()
                            .when(qClientMemo.createdDate.gt(LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(7)))
                            .then(1)
                            .otherwise(0).sum()

            )
            .from(qClientMemo);

    if ((!hasAdminRole) && writerId != null) {
        memoDtoJPAQuery = memoDtoJPAQuery.where(qClientMemo.writer.id.eq(writerId));
    }

    if (searchKeyword != null)
        memoDtoJPAQuery = memoDtoJPAQuery.where(
                qClientMemo.title.contains(searchKeyword)
                        .or(qClientMemo.content.contains(searchKeyword))
                        .or(qClientMemo.clientId.clientName.contains(searchKeyword))
                        .or(qClientMemo.writer.name.contains(searchKeyword))
        );

    return memoDtoJPAQuery
            .groupBy(qClientMemo.clientId)
            .orderBy(OrderByNull.DEFAULT)
            .fetch();
}
```

- generated query 1

```
select
    (select
        clientmemo1_.id 
    from
        client_memo clientmemo1_ 
    where
        clientmemo1_.client_id=clientmemo0_.client_id 
        and clientmemo1_.created_date=(
            select
                max(clientmemo2_.created_date) 
            from
                client_memo clientmemo2_ 
            where
                clientmemo2_.client_id=clientmemo0_.client_id
        )
    ) as col_0_0_, sum(case 
        when clientmemo0_.created_date>? then ? 
        else 0 
    end) as col_1_0_ 
from
    client_memo clientmemo0_ 
group by
    clientmemo0_.client_id 
order by
    null asc
```

- generated query 2

```
select
    [all fields of client_memo entity] 
from
    client_memo clientmemo0_ 
where
    clientmemo0_.id=?
```

- generated query 3

```
select
    [all fields of client entity]
from
    client client0_ 
where
    client0_.id=?
```

- ClientMemoServiceImpl.java

```
List<Tuple> clientMemos = clientMemoRepository.findAllByWriterGroupByClient(
                    readClientMemoDto.getSearchKeyword(),
                    readClientMemoDto.getUserId(),
                    hasAdminRole
            );

clientMemos.forEach(clientMemo -> {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();

    Integer newCnt = clientMemo.get(1, Integer.class);
    if (newCnt != null) {
        result.put("newMemoNum", newCnt);
    }

    MemoDto memoDto = new MemoDto();
    ClientMemo memo = clientMemo.get(0, ClientMemo.class);
    if (memo != null) {
        memoDto.ofClientMemo(memo);
        result.put("memoDetail", memoDto);
    }

    results.add(result);
});
```

- ClientMemo.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client_memo")
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicInsert
public class ClientMemo {

    @JsonIgnore
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
    private String title;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "content")
    private String content;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="client_id")
    private Client clientId;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="writer")
    private User writer;

    @Column(name = "created_date")
    private LocalDateTime createdDate;

    @Column(name = "updated_date")
    private LocalDateTime updatedDate;

    @Column(name = "is_admin")
    private boolean isAdmin;

}
```

- Client.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "client")
@Getter
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamicInsert
public class Client {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "client_name", nullable = false)
    private String clientName;

    @Column(name = "client_phone_num", nullable = false)
    private String clientPhoneNum;

    @Column(name = "service_start_time")
    private LocalDateTime serviceStartTime;

    @Column(name = "service_end_time")
    private LocalDateTime serviceEndTime;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "media_id")
    private Media media;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_charge_id")
    private User personCharge;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "normal_memo")
    private ClientMemo normalMemo;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "admin_memo")
    private ClientMemo adminMemo;

    @Column(name = "status", columnDefinition = "varchar(20) default 'UNCONTRACTED'")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private ClientStatus status;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted", nullable = false)
    private boolean isDeleted;

}
```

All `FetchType` of Data Relationship are `FetchType.LAZY`.

---

I don't understand why occur this problem and why some people say that better using `FetchType.LAZY` than `FetchType.EAGER`.

Do I understand QueryDSL or SpringBoot correctly?

Thanks

Comment: Please check Vlad's answer first: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27520593/3426309 Key point: if you/application/method want to get entity associations via single query you need to specify that in query and do not rely on JPA magic, because in the most cases eager associations tend to slow down application - we are forcing JPA to perform unnecessary work.

Comment: @AndreyB.Panfilov Thanks, I understand that I better to use LAZY mode because it make my application faster. Is this right? And I don't know what is the mean "do not rely on JPA magic" you mentioned

Comment: No, the point is completely different. Lazy associations do not make application faster, they give you a chance to perform further optimisations, i.e. when you are using eager associations you are forcing JPA to always return fully initialized entities (it could be done via two common ways: either constructing complex SQL queries or issuing extra SQL queries), while the business code is not even going to consume those associations - you have no chance to optimise eager associations, moreover, switching from eager to lazy is not a simple operation - it may break everything.

Answer (score 0):

You should share with us your Jpa entities.

In my opinion, you should have setted some associations in your entity (with @OneToMany, etc..), probably in Eager Mode (which is the default mode).

When you try to load one instance of your object from the database, Hibernate loads the associations as well. In eager mode, hibernate loads the associations by querying the database (which generates additional sql queries).

If you define your associations in Lazy mode, Hibernate will populate your entity jpa with some proxy objects and will fetch the associations later, only when you access it (so that means the sql query of your association is deffered when you only try to access the association in your code).

Comment: Thanks, I edited my question for share JPA entities with your.