# one to one mapping using primary key join column

Tags: hibernate, persistence

I have employee and employee detail classes mapped (bi directional)  using primary key join column (employee_id)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="employee")
public class Employee {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
@Column(name="employee_id")
private Long employeeId;

@Column(name="firstname")
private String firstname;

@Column(name="lastname")
private String lastname;

@Column(name="birth_date")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.DATE )
private Date birthDate;

@Column(name="cell_phone")
private String cellphone;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="empl", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private EmployeeDetail employeeDetail;

...
}



@Table(name="employeedetail")
public class EmployeeDetail {


@Id
@Column(name="employee_id", unique=true, nullable=false)
@GeneratedValue(generator="gen")
@GenericGenerator(name="gen", strategy="foreign", parameters=@Parameter(name="property", value="empl"))
private Long employeeId;

@Column(name="street")
private String street;

@Column(name="city")
private String city;

@Column(name="state")
private String state;

@Column(name="country")
private String country;

@OneToOne
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Employee empl;
....................
}
```

Can someone please clarify why when executing the following query session.createQuery("from Employee").list();

A) the join queries like 2),3) and 4) get executed to fetch data from employeedetail? 
    why not directly fetch from employeedetail table using the employeeid value in employee object without a join?

```
1) Hibernate: select employee0_.employee_id as employee1_0_, employee0_.birth_date as birth_da2_0_, employee0_.cell_phone as cell_pho3_0_, employee0_.firstname as firstnam4_0_, employee0_.lastname as lastname5_0_ from employee employee0_ 

2) Hibernate: select employeede0_.employee_id as employee1_1_0_, employeede0_.city as city2_1_0_, employeede0_.country as country3_1_0_, employeede0_.state as state4_1_0_, employeede0_.street as street5_1_0_, employee1_.employee_id as employee1_0_1_, employee1_.birth_date as birth_da2_0_1_, employee1_.cell_phone as cell_pho3_0_1_, employee1_.firstname as firstnam4_0_1_, employee1_.lastname as lastname5_0_1_ from employeedetail employeede0_ left outer join employee employee1_ on employeede0_.employee_id=employee1_.employee_id where employeede0_.employee_id=? 
3) Hibernate: select employeede0_.employee_id as employee1_1_0_, employeede0_.city as city2_1_0_, employeede0_.country as country3_1_0_, employeede0_.state as state4_1_0_, employeede0_.street as street5_1_0_, employee1_.employee_id as employee1_0_1_, employee1_.birth_date as birth_da2_0_1_, employee1_.cell_phone as cell_pho3_0_1_, employee1_.firstname as firstnam4_0_1_, employee1_.lastname as lastname5_0_1_ from employeedetail employeede0_ left outer join employee employee1_ on employeede0_.employee_id=employee1_.employee_id where employeede0_.employee_id=? 
4) Hibernate: select employeede0_.employee_id as employee1_1_0_, employeede0_.city as city2_1_0_, employeede0_.country as country3_1_0_, employeede0_.state as state4_1_0_, employeede0_.street as street5_1_0_, employee1_.employee_id as employee1_0_1_, employee1_.birth_date as birth_da2_0_1_, employee1_.cell_phone as cell_pho3_0_1_, employee1_.firstname as firstnam4_0_1_, employee1_.lastname as lastname5_0_1_ from employeedetail employeede0_ left outer join employee employee1_ on employeede0_.employee_id=employee1_.employee_id where employeede0_.employee_id=?
```

B) also, for the query session.createQuery("from EmployeeDetail").list();

```
why employee info is fetched as per below select queries instead of being proxied? 


Hibernate: select employeede0_.employee_id as employee1_1_, employeede0_.city as city2_1_, employeede0_.country as country3_1_, employeede0_.state as state4_1_, employeede0_.street as street5_1_ from employeedetail employeede0_ 

Hibernate: select employee0_.employee_id as employee1_0_0_, employee0_.birth_date as birth_da2_0_0_, employee0_.cell_phone as cell_pho3_0_0_, employee0_.firstname as firstnam4_0_0_, employee0_.lastname as lastname5_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.employee_id=? 
Hibernate: select employee0_.employee_id as employee1_0_0_, employee0_.birth_date as birth_da2_0_0_, employee0_.cell_phone as cell_pho3_0_0_, employee0_.firstname as firstnam4_0_0_, employee0_.lastname as lastname5_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.employee_id=? 
Hibernate: select employee0_.employee_id as employee1_0_0_, employee0_.birth_date as birth_da2_0_0_, employee0_.cell_phone as cell_pho3_0_0_, employee0_.firstname as firstnam4_0_0_, employee0_.lastname as last`enter code here`name5_0_0_ from employee employee0_ where employee0_.employee_id=?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A) It is a little bit weird, and Hibernate could do it better. However, this is due to the fact that `Employee` is loaded eagerly in `EmployeeDetail`, and Hibernate wants to avoid additional queries to load the corresponding employee for each `EmployeeDetail`. It could do it better because the corresponding employees are already loaded with the first query.

This should disappear if you apply my advice in B).

B) By default, one-to-one associations are eager in JPA. To make it lazy:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Employee empl;
```

However, keep in mind the behavior of one-to-one associations described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy). If Hibernate cannot determine whether the proxied object in one-to-one relation exists or is `null`, then additional query will be executed anyway to check this.

To overcome this, if `empl` is mandatory for each `EmployeeDetail` (and it is in your use case, an employee detail cannot exist without the employee), then indicate it in the association mapping:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private Employee empl;
```

This way Hibernate will make a proxy containing only `Employee` id when loading `EmployeeDetail` entity instances without querying `employee` table at all.

Comment: If I want to use `OneToOne` with cascade delete (when `Employee` deleted, `EmployeeDetails` also deleted), how it would be with `PrimaryKeyJoinColumn`?

Answer (score 0):

> Can someone please clarify why when executing the following query session.createQuery("from Employee").list();

This should be happening because your `employee` table must have 3 entries. Since it is a one-to-one mapping, for each row returned from employee it will fire a query to fetch its `employeedetail`. So the three queries.

> B) also, for the query session.createQuery("from EmployeeDetail").list();

Proxies are only created for lazily loaded entities.