# Hibernate eagerly loads lazy reference

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-leaks, lazy-loading, eager-loading

I have three Entities A, B and C.

```
@Entity
public class A {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  public B b;
}

@Entity
public class B {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  public C c;
}

@Entity
public class C {
  @Id
  private long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
  public B b;
}
```

So there is an eagerly loaded reference of B in A and between B and C is a lazily loaded bidirectional relation.

My problem: When fetching an instance of A from the DB, an instance of C is fetched as well by Hibernate.

I discovered it in a heap dump due to a memory leak and tested it programmatically:

```
@Test
public void eagerAndLazyLoading() {
  A a = dao.getA(1L);

  Assert.assertNotNull(a);

  PersistenceUnitUtil puu = emf.getPersistenceUnitUtil();

  Assert.assertTrue(puu.isLoaded(a));
  Assert.assertTrue(puu.isLoaded(a, "b"));
  Assert.assertFalse(puu.isLoaded(a.b, "c"));
}
```

That last Assert fails.

Luckily there was no problem getting rid of the bidirectional relation, but I would like to know the source of the problem.
Is it the intended behaviour of Hibernate to eagerly load all references of an entity, that is eagerly loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is some problem with OneToOne Lazy loading. There is post in Hibernate forums explaining why and giving some advices( https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=1001116 ). I would suggest to try search before you ask.
Also I think this was already asked here and got also really good answer: Try this one: [Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Obviously I couldn't find it myself, because I thought it only mattered for eager loaded entities, not every OneToOne-Relationship.