# Spring Data Jpa - Lazy fetch mode not working for @OneToOne

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I tried with this :

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private UserInfo userInfo;
```

But the above code doesn't fetch lazily.

And also tried with the following code :

```
@Entity
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "User.detail", attributeNodes = {} )
public class User extends AbstractEntity {

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "country", nullable = false)
    private Country country;

    @Column(name = "mobile_no", nullable = false)
    private String mobileNo;

    @Column(name = "password", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private UserInfo userInfo;

    // Getter & setter
}
```

---

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(value = "User.detail", type = EntityGraphType.FETCH)
    User findById(Long id);
}
```

This too doesn't work.

*Can anybody help me?*

Comment: Does every User have a UserInfo? If so, you should mark the association as optional=false. Otherwise, Hibernate has no idea if it must set the field to null or to a proxy, and is thus force to check if a UserInfo exists for the user.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy

Comment: @jbnizet, I tried using optional=false, but it's not working. I also tried with @LazyToOne(value = LazyToOneOption.PROXY), but still not working.

Answer (score 1):

As per JPA 2.1 (JSR 338) specification, section 11.1.41 the value `FetchType.LAZY` for the parameter `fetch` is only a hint:

> Whether the association should be lazily loaded or must be eagerly fetched. The 
>   `EAGER` strategy is a requirement on the persistence provider runtime that the associated entity **must be eagerly fetched**. The `LAZY` strategy **is a hint** to the persistence provider runtime.

So if the association is eagerly fetched it does not mean that `FetchType.LAZY` dose not work (as specified).

A possible solution to your problem could be to remove `private UserInfo userInfo;` from your entity mapping and add a `fetchUserInfo(Long userId)` to your `UserRepository`.