# Hibernate is loading lazy objects without being asked for

Tags: hibernate, lazy-loading

In order to keep transfered data small I created two entities for my files in the database. The fileheader to keep some general informations about the files and the fileblob, including fileId and the blob.
Often, I only need to ask for general fileinformations. If I now ask for a list of fileheaders, hibernate unfortunatelly selects the fileblob too (each one in a single select). So here is my example:

Extract from Fileh.class:

```
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "fileh", targetEntity = Fileblob.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK })
  private Fileblob fileblob;
```

Extract from selection:

```
  Criteria createCriteria = persistentSession.createCriteria(Fileh.class);

  List list = createCriteria.list();
```

ConsoleLog:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        this_.`ID` as ID1_78_0_,
        this_.`CHDATE` as CHDATE2_78_0_,
        this_.`CHUSER` as CHUSER9_78_0_,
        this_.`CRDATE` as CRDATE3_78_0_,
        this_.`CRUSER` as CRUSER10_78_0_,
        this_.`EXTENSION` as EXTENSIO4_78_0_,
        this_.`NAME` as NAME5_78_0_,
        this_.`SIZE` as SIZE6_78_0_,
        this_.`VALID_FROM` as VALID_FR7_78_0_,
        this_.`VALID_TO` as VALID_TO8_78_0_ 
    from
        CORE.`FILEH` this_
Hibernate: 
    select
        fileblob0_.`ID` as ID1_77_0_,
        fileblob0_.`FILEBLOB` as FILEBLOB2_77_0_ 
    from
        CORE.`FILEBLOB` fileblob0_ 
    where
        fileblob0_.`ID`=?
Hibernate: 
    select
        fileblob0_.`ID` as ID1_77_0_,
        fileblob0_.`FILEBLOB` as FILEBLOB2_77_0_ 
    from
        CORE.`FILEBLOB` fileblob0_ 
    where
        fileblob0_.`ID`=? .....(and so on)
```

Am I wrong with my assumption, that **fetch = FetchType.LAZY** should be sufficient for my purpose?

Thanks in advance for your hints and suggestions. I just think I´m barking up the wrong tree...

Kind regards,
Vincent

**Edit:** Started to dive into hibernate sourcecode. In `DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(...)` hibernate decides weather to load as proxy or not. In my example following option is passed: `LoadEventListener.INTERNAL_LOAD_NULLABLE` which results in accessing the database. Just don´t understand why yet....

**Edit2:** Problem solved: added `optional = false` to OneToOne-annotation:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "fileh", targetEntity = Fileblob.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
  @org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK })
  private Fileblob fileblob;
```

Comment: Make sure while iterating **Fileh** list , **`Fileblob`** object is not getting accessed .

Comment: Hi @rigal, thanks fo your comment, but I´m not accessing the attribute. It seems to be automatically unproxied somewhere in createCriteria.list().....

Comment: Problem solved, adding 'optional = false' in the OneToOne-annotation does the trick. See [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, adding `optional = false` in the OneToOne-annotation does the trick.

See similarity [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)