# Hibernate OneToOne: Forced to chose between optional = false or cascade?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

In order to keep transfered data small I created two entities for my files in the database. The `fileheader` to keep some general information about the files and the `fileblob`, including `fileId` and the blob. Often, I only need to ask for general `fileinformations`.

So I need to load the `fileblobs` lazily.

As I learned in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43678271/hibernate-is-loading-lazy-objects-without-being-asked-for) and [that discussion.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy) this could be achieved with `optional = false`. It works perfect to load the `fileblobs` lazily. Unfortunately it affects save by cascade.

So here is my attribute in the `Fileh.class` for the blob:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "fileh", targetEntity = Fileblob.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({ org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK })
private Fileblob fileblob;
```

If I now save a `fileh` with attached `fileblob`, this error is thrown:

> org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: null id generated
>   for:class Fileblob

if i switch from id-generation strategy "identity" to "increment" this error is thrown:

> ```
> ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:147 - Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`CORE`.`FILEBLOB`, CONSTRAINT
> ```
>
> `FKFILEBLOB412557` FOREIGN KEY (`ID`) REFERENCES `FILEH` (`ID`))
>       Query is: insert into CORE.`FILEBLOB` (`FILEBLOB`, `ID`) values (?, ?)

So there is a problem with generating the id...
If i now turn off save by cascade my attribute looks like this.

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "fileh", targetEntity = Fileblob.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Fileblob fileblob;
```

In order to save now, I have to call

```
persistentSession.saveOrUpdate(fileh);
persistentSession.saveOrUpdate(fileblob);
```

Is this not just what `CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE` is supposed to do?
Why is this working for "manual cascading" but not automatically?

P.s.: To complete my example here the counterpart in `fileblob.class`

```
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn   
@OneToOne(targetEntity=Fileh.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)   
@org.hibernate.annotations.Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.SAVE_UPDATE, org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.LOCK}) 
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name="`ID`", referencedColumnName="`ID`", unique=true, nullable=false) })    
private Fileh fileh;

@Column(name="`ID`", nullable=false, insertable=false, updatable=false, unique=true)    
@Id 
@GeneratedValue(generator="FILEBLOB_FILEHID_GENERATOR") 
@org.hibernate.annotations.GenericGenerator(name="FILEBLOB_FILEHID_GENERATOR", strategy="foreign", parameters=@org.hibernate.annotations.Parameter(name="property", value="fileh")) 
private int filehId;
```

Comment: just to be clear, should Fileblob.id be the same as Fileh.id?

Comment: yes, a shared primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well first i would use JPA cascading instead of hibernate one:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "fileh", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
private Fileblob fileblob;
```

And the Fileblob, well i think your configuration can be a bit simpler without those generators and stuff(assuming that the id should be actually a foreign key pointing to the Fileh.id).

```
@Column(name="`ID`", nullable=false, unique=true)    
@Id 
private int filehId;

@JoinColumn(name = "id", referencedColumnName = "id")
@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
@MapsId
private Fileh fileh;
```

Comment: Hi Maciej, thank you for your answer! If I switch to JPA cascading, it is not cascading, the fileblob is missing in the database if I only save the fileheader. Am I missing something else?

Comment: how do you assemble the entities before save? Also check the update @Column(name="`ID`", nullable=false, unique=true)

Comment: I call the setters viceverca: fileh.setfileblob(fileblob) and fileblob.setfileh(fileh). The @Column is updated as you considered.

Comment: try to set only this side: `fileblob.setfileh(fileh)` and save the blob entity `saveOrUpdate(fileblob)`

Comment: unfortunatly just the same behaviour. I´m afraid JPA cascading has no affect, I just wonder why....

Comment: ok i have went through my notes and updated the answer. keep saving only the fileblob

Comment: Hooray, seems to work right now. I will just switch this, so I only have to save the fileh. Just wonder what was wrong in my approach. The missing @MapsId? Using hibernate annotations? Will do some experiments and then edit my post. Thx for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

I encountered exactly the same issue and tried to solve it for several days! It turns out **it's an issue which has lied in Hibernate's bug system for more than 2 years!**

Though the answer here does help resolve the issue, we are forced to give up using Persist Cascade from the parent Entity (the inverse side, also the side with **mappedBy** defined)

Please see this link: https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-9670

If you want to apply lazy loading to a OneToOne relationship, and be able to do Persist cascade as usual, please leave a comment to show your concern for the issue!

Comment: thank you for your answer, also left some words in bug's comment