# Hibernate @OneToOne relationship - Preventing Eager loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data

The following are various methods to prevent eager loading of @OneToOne relationships

1. Use @MapsId as described [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) - Tried this but didn't work
2. Fake a @One-Many relationaship but this could lead to issues with complicated JPQL  queries.
3. @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, optional=false) - I don't have non-nullable items
4. Buildtime Byte Code Instrumentation - Again, I don't have non-nullable one-one relationships and hence will again not work in my case.

As a result, I think only option1 and option2 are suitable ones in my case. I know this topic has been discussed well like [here in this excellent discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy). But those answers are almost 5-8 years back and was wondering if there are new methods now.

I have the following specific questions

1. What are the situations under which @MapsId wouldn't work ?
2. Are there any other issues with faking a @One-Many relationship as mentioned in option 2 above
3. Are there any new alternatives in the new versions of Hibernate ?

Comment: Why would nullable one-to-one relationships be an issue with byte code instrumentation? With non-nullable relationships, you don't need instrumentation, because Hibernate can always use a proxy instead of an actual entity, knowing it will never have to be replaced with `null`

Comment: Need to clarify: I have relationships that could be null. So sometimes null and sometimes not-null.

Comment: I understand that. Let me rephrase: were your one-to-one relationship non-nullable, solution #3 would be the standard way of achieving lazy fetching (it would work out of the box). The other solutions are *all about finding a workaround* for nullable one-to-one relationships. I'm just saying this includes #4, which I think is the least hacky solution to your problem.

Comment: Well, you were right ! I added a foreign key to the owner table and it worked. I haven't listed that as an option above, but seems to work fine. Thanks for your time.