# How nested FETCH JOIN works on Hibernate using JpaRepository and @Query annotation?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jakarta-ee

I have the following problem (pseudo-java-code):

Let me a class A,B,C with the following relationships:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A {

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
  private B b; 

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "a_id")
  private A a;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "b", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private C c;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "C")
public class C {

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "b_id")
  private B b;

}
```

I'm using JpaRepository with @Query annotation and I implemented the following query:

```
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT(a) FROM A a "
        + "LEFT JOIN FETCH a.b as b"
        + "WHERE a.id = :id ")
A findById(@Param("id") Integer id);
```

I want retrieve the informations about class A and B, but not C.
Somehow (I don't know why) the query try to retrive also the relation between B and C.
And then, with hibernate, start the lazy invocation for retrieving C.

Naturally, if I fetch also the relation between B and C (adding `LEFT JOIN FETCH b.c as c`) that's not happen.

My question is, why? Why I'm forced to fetch all nested relations and not only the ones which I need?

thank you.
Carmelo

Comment: It's the default behavior to load lazily all the properties that is annotated with `@OneToMany`. If you don't want then don't use that annotation.

Comment: @ErfanAhmedEmon I don't think that the problem was the `@OneToMany` relation, but is explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47652652/4149078

Thank you for your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nullable @OneToOne relation are always eager fetched as explained in this post 
[Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

> Unconstrained (nullable) one-to-one association is the only one that
>   can not be proxied without bytecode instrumentation. The reason for
>   this is that owner entity MUST know whether association property
>   should contain a proxy object or NULL and it can't determine that by
>   looking at its base table's columns due to one-to-one normally being
>   mapped via shared PK, so it has to be eagerly fetched anyway making
>   proxy pointless.

Comment: Yes, I found the same post, and I understood why.
Is definitly the best explication about this behavior.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Shot in the dark, but there are some issues with lazy-loading `@OneToOne`-relationships. At least in older versions of `Hibernate`. I think (but can't seem to find any documentation) that this was fixed in one of the newer versions, so if you are not using a new version of Hibernate, try upgrading.

Comment: I'm using the 5.0.7.Final version.