# How to lazy fetch child entity from parent in OneToOne relationship?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to fetch lazy the child entity from parent entity in one-to-one relationship.

I tried adding `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)` in the parent side. Also i tried `@MapsId` as described in this [post](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) & [post2](http://justonjava.blogspot.in/2010/09/lazy-one-to-one-and-one-to-many.html). But child entity is still fetching eagerly. Below is my entity class, what change I should do to achieve laziness.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "POST")
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "post", cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    private PostDetails details;

    //getters and setters
}


@Entity
@Table(name = "POST_DETAILS")
public class PostDetails {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    private String comment;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId
    private Post post;

    //getters and setters
}


(Post)session.get(Post.class, 1L);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

Comment: The one suggested is I have tried and I even specified that in the question. It is not working.

Comment: To make it short. It's not possible it the @OneToOne is optional=true (that's the default of OneToOne)