# @OneToOne mapping with lazy loading in Hibernate / JPA 2.1 not working?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.0

I am using JPA 2.1 and Hibernate for implementation.

Take a sample example :

I have a parent entity(call it Parent) and a child entity ( call it Child ).

**UniqueKey Embeddable :**

```
@Embeddable
@EqualsAndHashCode
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
public class UniqueKey implements Serializable {

    public UniqueKey(String id1, String id2) {
        this.id1 = id1;
        this.id2 = id2;
    }

    @Column(name = "id1")
    private String id1;

    @Column(name = "id2")
    private String id2;
}
```

**Parent Entity :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "parent", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {
                "id1",
                "id2"
        })
})
public class Parent implements Serializable {
   @Id
   private UniqueKey key;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "id1", referencedColumnName = "id1", insertable = false,
                    updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "id2", referencedColumnName = "id2", insertable = false,
                    updatable = false)
    })
    private Child child;
}
```

**Child Entity :**

```
public class Child implements Serializable {
   @EmbeddedId
   private UniqueKey key;

   @Column(name = "name")
   private String name;
}
```

For some query on Parent I need child and for some case I don't need.

I am trying to fetching by uniqueKey but not calling getChild() but it is still fetch child data along with parent.

After referring [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1445694/6497665). It says in case of @OneToOne it always fetch data eagerly even if we define fetch = FetchType.LAZY .As this is very old answer so I don't know if it also happen with JPA 2.1 .

> If it also happen in JPA 2.1 then what are other way for Fetch lazy
>   using JPA criteriaBuilder ?

Answer (score 0):

1. Lazy `@OnetoOne` relations to actually work
2. If you need to select `UniqueKey` of from parent without fetching child — you may try following:

   class UniqueKeyDto {
     private String s1;
     private String s2;
     UniqueKeyDto(String s1, String s2){
       // omitted
     }
   }

And then use JPQL query like this:

```
SELECT NEW UniqueKeyDto(p.child.key.s1, p.child.key.s2) FROM Parent p WHERE <conditions here>
```

This query can be obviously optimized, but I'm not sure which JPA implementations can do this in reality.

If your implementation doesn't support this kind of optimizations then your way — is native query. It's perfectly fine to make native queries sometimes :)

Comment: I need dynamic query which CriteriaBuilder provide while JPQL don't. Thats why I am not preferring JPQL. Btw Thanks for your input.