# Fetchtype.LAZY behaving like Fetchtype.EAGER with OneToOne mapping

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, hibernate-mapping

I am having `user`(`user_id` PK) entity which has `One-to-One` association with `mentor_profile` entity. Then the `mentor_profile` has `One-to-Many` association with `mentor_history`.
The primary key of `mentor_profile` is the shared PK from user table i.e user_id.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
   @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
   private Integer userId;

   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "user")
   private MentorProfile mentorProfile;
```

mentor_profile

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "mentor_profile")
public class MentorProfile {

    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "user"))
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    @Column(name = "user_id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private int userId;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private User user;

    @Column(name = "is_looking_mentee")
    private Boolean isLookingMentee;
```

But when a `select` query on `user` is triggered, all the associated One-to-One entities(with shared key of user) also get selected even I am using FetchType>LAZY.

```
Hibernate: select user0_.user_id as user_id1_43_, user0_.about as about2_43_ ............ from user user0_ where user0_.first_name=?
Hibernate: select mentorprof0_.user_id as user_id1_29_0_, ............. from mentor_profile mentorprof0_ where mentorprof0_.user_id=?
Hibernate: select trainerpro0_.user_id as user_id1_42_0_, ............. from trainer_profile trainerpro0_ where trainerpro0_.user_id=?
```

**The basic idea behind this model is:** user can have similar roles like mentor, e.g trainer. And if the user is mentor, there are certain mentor specific columns. E.g when he/she started mentoring, if he is available to mentoring etc. Since these details are employment(mentor, trainer) specific, these cannot be stored under user table. Because with that design, if a user is mentor then all the columns related to trainer will be blank, which is a bad design. According to [high performance mysql](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920022343.do), one should always avoid null values in the DB, they cost us memory and performance. So separating the `user`'s profession with `xx_profile` solves this problem.

**Is it the shared-key which is causing the issue?**

Comment: see here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy

Answer (score 0):

Lazy does not work on OneToOne mapping. Better change to @ManyToOne, Lazy will work on it.

Comment: I tried a test. I deleted all the One-to-One mappings from user entity. And respective mapping from xx_profile entities. Now if I select the user, non of the profile entities are getting loaded eagerly. The main reason to use One-to-One was to operate on Cascading. If the user delete his account, respective profile should also get deleted. And since I am using ON DELETE = CASCADE on the DB side, the deletion of profile is handled by DB. And this solved by business.