# Spring JPA : Update entity with updated child entities

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, one-to-one, hibernate-onetomany

DB Used : Postgres with Spring jpa

I have a Main Entity which has structure as follows :

```
Parent (CascadeType.All for childs)
-->Child 1 (Join column with parent here)
-->Child 2 (Join column with parent here)
-->Child 3 (Join column with parent here)
-->Child 4 (Join column with parent here)
-->Child 5 (Join column with parent here)
```

When I first save parent entity in db(Child 2..5 are null) it saves successfully. Then i update Child 2..5 and do save operation with same object it gives me error that it exceeds no of column size of Postgres which is 1665.(This is because child has nested childrens)

I tried to update Child 2 ..5 by removing *CascadeType.ALL* with their repository object but it says *"object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance before flushing"*.

Please advise how to resolve this. Thanks

```
public class Parent {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child1 child1;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child1 child2;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child1 child3;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child1 child4;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child1 child5;

    //getters setters
}

public class Child1 {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = FKNAME)
    private Parent parent1;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private GrandChild1 child1;

    //getters setters   
}

public class GrandChild1 {
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = FKNAME)
    private Child1 child1;

    //getters setters   
}

parentRepository.save(parent);
```

Exception :

```
2018-09-04 08:12:07 WARN  SqlExceptionHelper:127 [1111] - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 54000
2018-09-04 08:12:07 ERROR SqlExceptionHelper:129 [1111] - ERROR: target lists can have at most 1664 entries
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaSystemException: could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:333)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:503)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:209)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy136.saveAndFlush(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:738)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet
```

Comment: show your code, how you are saving parent object?

Comment: @AngadBansode : I am using parentRepository.save(parent-obj) to save into db.

Comment: which relationship have parent to child, i mean @OneToMany or other

Comment: @AngadBansode : I have updated the code.

Comment: The  @JoinColumn is useless. Remove this.

Comment: You identified the problem as being related to "This is because child has nested childrens" but you don't show that relationship. Please add the relevant code.

Comment: @JensSchauder : I have updated my code. Some childs also have OneToMany. I wanted to save child when i save parent. When i create child object in parent and try to save(which is hibernate update) it fails as it exceeds postgres fetch col size.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli : I have constraint on child table that parent FK should not be null. And it owns relationship. I maybe wrong as i am new to JPA.

Comment: How is `GrandChild1` relevant to this? It isn't referenced from the other classes.

Comment: Please add the exception with the complete stack trace (formatted as code), please.

Comment: @JensSchauder : Updated question. GrandChild is child of Child1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179349/discussion-between-rohan-lopes-and-jens-schauder).

Comment: The problem is that Hibernate joins all these relationships and then Postgres cannot execute the query. Try adding FetchType.LAZY to the mappings

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate tries to fetch eager 1-1 relationships by joining the relevant tables and including the required columns in the select clause.

Since you have an infinite cascade of 1-1 relationships this causes problems on finite computers.

Break the chain of relationships by declaring at least one element of the chain as lazy and the problem should go away.

Note that (at least in the distant past) it wasn't always completely easy to pull it of, but there is a SO question which should help: [Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)