# Hibernate OneToONe Lazy Fetching

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, lazy-loading, one-to-one

I know this question was asked several times but I couldn't find a clear example and answer about this topic(I also tried other possible solutions).

I am using `Spring JPA` and `Hibernate` and trying to make a lazy fetch for a OneToONe relation. I have 2 simple Entity classes, one Repository class and using h2 database to lazy load an entity. I tried build time bytecode instrumentation to achive this and these are my classes.

**Class A**

```
@Entity
public class A {

    private String name;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "a")
    @LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)
    private B b;
}
```

**Class B**

```
@Entity
public class B {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID")
    private A a;
}
```

**Repository**

```
public interface ARepository extends JpaRepository<A, Long> {
    A findByName(String name);
}
```

**pom.xml** bytecode enhancer

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.orm.tooling</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-enhance-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <failOnError>true</failOnError>
                <enableLazyInitialization>true</enableLazyInitialization>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>enhance</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and lastly **initdata.sql** for h2 database

```
insert into a (name, id) values ('a', 1);
insert into b (a_id, id) values (1, 1);
```

When I call `findByName()` method in a test class it still executes 2 queries for `A` and `B`. How can I lazy fetch `B` class ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have the same problem too, hope someone already solved this issue

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy

Comment: I already checked it.

Comment: Did you find the answer? In my experience, if you'll use a shared primary key for both tables then it'll work. I faced the same problem and shared primary key is not an option

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-lazy-loading-one-to-one/) tutorial has answer on your qustions

> That’s because Hibernate needs to know if it shall initialize the manuscript attribute with null or a proxy class. It can only find that out, by querying the manuscript table to find a record that references this Book entity. The Hibernate team decided that if they have to query the manuscript table anyways, it’s best to fetch the associated entity eagerly.

Answer (score -1):

As I know it is imposible to avoid 2 queries, because Hibernate needs to know what should be inserted in your "one to one field" - proxy or null. Proxy is inserted to your object if theres is related record in secondary table, NULL if there isn't any records. So hibernate execute second query to make a check. 
Insted "one to one" you can use "many to one"

Comment: I read some articles about build time bytecode instrumentation and most of the people says that it is possible. I think I missed something in my code structure, but thanks for your answer.