# How to make optional one to one mapping using JPA and hibernate and avoid N+1 selects?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I want to model an optional one to one mapping with JPA.

`tableA` has a column (`flag`) and when that is `true` I need to select additional data from an other `tableB` to get a string.

tableB has a fk to the pk of tableA.

So far I tiered this mapping but hibernates makes additional selects for tableB per default. I only want those when I access the mapping to tableB.

Class TableA

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy= tableA_id, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
private TableB tableB;
```

Class TableB

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy= tableA_id, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "TABLEA_ID"
private TableA tableA
```

The result is that I get selects on tableB just from a 
`em.createQuery("from TableA")` before even accessing `getTableB()`.

Comment: Sure, just model your dependency as a (optional) @OneToOne relationship - you tried this?

Comment: @Smutje what is an optional OneToOne relationship? You mean a lazy init OneToOne? And then call the getter for that inside the EntityA. Hmm that could work I have not thought about that simple solution.

Comment: No, it can be EAGER or LAZY, as long as it is optional (which it is by default for @OneToOne) - from the doc: `(Optional) Whether the association is optional. If set to false then a non-null relationship must always exist.`

Comment: @Smutje optional = true Does not work. Maybe because of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy