# why LazyInitializationException was not thrown?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data

I created the entity `Org` that has a one to one mapping with `OrgHV`

```java
@Table(name="ORG_CHART")
@Entity
public class Org {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ORG_ID")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ORG_ID")
    private OrgHV orgHV;
    //getters and Setters
}
```

In the service I retrieved all entities of `Org` using Spring data Jpa repo and because of lazy loading `OrgHV` will not be fetched until I call `org.getOrgHV()`. The problem is I am doing so after I called `repo.findAll()`, so the session/transaction is closed (correct me if I am wrong)? Why the code is working fine, why `LazyInitializationException` is not thrown?

```java
public orgService()
{
   List<Org> orgs = orgRepo.findAll();
   for (Org org: orgs) 
   {  
      orgRepo.findAll();  
      OrgHV orgHv = org.getOrgHV();
      System.out.pringLn(orgHv.getId());
   }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)

Comment: I am also curious why LazyInitializationException is not thrown in this example. FetchType is LAZY, transaction is finished, so why it is working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exception is not thrown, because of `spring.jpa.open-in-view` property, by default set to true ([source](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html)), which registers `OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor`. This binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request, so even though `findAll()` method finishes as well as the transaction, still lazy loaded fields can be fetched.

As stated in the [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/support/OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor.html)

> Spring web request interceptor binds a JPA EntityManager to the thread for the entire processing of the request. Intended for the "Open EntityManager in View" pattern, i.e. **to allow for lazy loading in web views despite the original transactions already being completed**.

You are even warned about that when Spring-Boot application starts (if that property is not explicitly set):

```
WARN 8363 --- [           main] JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
```

If you want to see the expected exception, set in the application.properties

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=false
```