# JPA @OneToOne n+1 query

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-one

There are entities in `@OneToOne` relationship.

```java
class Region {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long pk;

  @OneToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "polygon_pk")
  private Polygon polygon;
}

class Polygon {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private long pk;
  
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "polygon", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  private Region region;
}
```

I expected below when I select `Region` Entity.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM region r
LEFT JOIN polygon p
on r.polygon_pk = p.pk
```

But actual query is below

```sql
SELECT *
FROM region r;

SELECT * 
FROM polygon p
WHERE p.pk in (?, ?, ?, ?, ...);

-- The query below occurs in the total number.
SELECT *
FROM region r
LEFT JOIN polygon p
on r.polygon_pk = p.pk
where r.pk = ?;

SELECT *
FROM region r
LEFT JOIN polygon p
on r.polygon_pk = p.pk
where r.pk = ?;

SELECT *
FROM region r
LEFT JOIN polygon p
on r.polygon_pk = p.pk
where r.pk = ?;

SELECT *
FROM region r
LEFT JOIN polygon p
on r.polygon_pk = p.pk
where r.pk = ?;

...
```

We cannot remove `@OneToOne` relationship on `Polygon` right now.
So, what thing I did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried adding an entity graph?

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/how-can-i-make-a-jpa-onetoone-relation-lazy
`OneToOne` lazy loading is not as straight as others can be.