# Lazy fetching with @OneToOne

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two *@OneToOne* entities:

```
...
public class A {
  
   ...
   
   @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
   @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", nullable = false)
   private B b; 

   ...
}

...
public class B {

...

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "b", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private A a;

...
}
```

and I'm using spring data JPA *JpaRepository<T, ID>* to fetch all entities (*findAll()* method).

Is it possible to fetch all *B* entities with lazily initialized *A* property (to not fetch *A* property whenever I fetch all *B* entities? If not, is it possible to avoid N+1 select in this case?

Edit: My question is different from How can I make a JPA OneToOne relation lazy [How can I make a JPA OneToOne relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/how-can-i-make-a-jpa-onetoone-relation-lazy) because mine is other way around, I want to fetch parent entities and/or to avoid N+1 select while fetching it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make a JPA OneToOne relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/how-can-i-make-a-jpa-onetoone-relation-lazy)

Comment: Nope, my problem is other way around. How to fetch parent entities, with "mappedBy".

Answer (score 0):

> Edit: My question is different from How can I make a JPA OneToOne
> relation lazy How can I make a JPA OneToOne relation lazy because mine
> is other way around, I want to fetch parent entities and/or to avoid
> N+1 select while fetching it.

The *only* way you can do it is to change your `@OneToOne` association to **uni-directional**.

But you are using a **bi-directional** `@OneToOne` association, so it's **not** possible***. The parent-association will always do a `FetchType.EAGER`. The reason being that

> For every managed entity, the "Persistence Context" needs both the
> entity type and the identifier, so the child identifier must be known
> when loading the parent entity, and the only way to find the
> associated "class A" primary key is to execute a second select.

***: If you want to avoid the second select, [Bytecode enhancement](https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-enable-bytecode-enhancement-dirty-checking-in-hibernate/) is the only viable workaround. However, it only works if the parent side is annotated with `@LazyToOne(LazyToOneOption.NO_PROXY)` and the child side is **not** using `@MapsId`.

**BONUS:**
*The most efficient way* to map a @OneToOne is described by the great Vlad [here](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/). In short, use `@MapsId`.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to fetch all B entities with lazily initialized A
> property (to not fetch A property whenever I fetch all B entities? If
> not, is it possible to avoid N+1 select in this case?

Maybe it's possible when you use property access rather than field access. With field access the one-to-one association has to initialized eagerly because it can't use a proxy. It can't because the field would have to be null if the object does not exist. With property access this can be deferred to the first call to a getter, but that might be a problem as well.

Maybe you can use a fetch join to avoid the N + 1 problem or use a DTO?