# What does CascadeType.MERGE actually do?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I got the `UserDetails` entity form database and passed it as model attribute (MVC). Later, I tried to update the updated `UserDetails` entity in database.
Now I am getting this error.
**My doubts are**

1. What is the use case of `CascadeType.MERGE`
2. How Hibernate handles entities
3. How can I update existing entity which is associated with another entity.

> Multiple representations of the same entity [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails#1] are being merged. Managed: [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails@637bce04]; Detached: [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails@2b6247fa]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails#1] are being merged. Managed: [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails@637bce04]; Detached: [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails@2b6247fa]] with root cause
> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple representations of the same entity [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails#1] are being merged. Managed: [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails@637bce04]; Detached: [com.rajath.instagram.entity.UserDetails@2b6247fa]

Controller Layer:

```java
@PostMapping("/addUserDetails")
public String adduserDetails(@ModelAttribute("user") UserDetails userDetails) {
   User user = (User) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
   regisrationService.updateUserDetails(user.getUsername(), userDetails);
   return "redirect:/register/addProfilePhoto";
}
```

Service Layer:

```java
@Override
@Transactional
public void updateUserDetails(String username, UserDetails userDetails) {
    
    Optional<InstagramUser> opt = instagramUserJpaDao.findById(username);
    InstagramUser user = opt.get();

    userDetails.setUser(user);
    userDetailsJpaDao.saveAndFlush(userDetails);
}
```

Dao Layer:

```java
@Override
public void updateUserDetails(String username, UserDetails userDetails) {

    Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
    InstagramUser user = session.get(InstagramUser.class, username);
    userDetails.setUser(user);
        
    user.setUserDetails(userDetails);
    session.saveOrUpdate(userDetails);
}
```

My entities are:

1. Instagramuser

```java
// From user details table
@OneToOne(mappedBy="user", fetch=FetchType.LAZY,            cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private UserDetails userDetails;
```

2. UserDetails

```java
    // From user table, @OneToOne matching because, only one user details entry for a user
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER,
          cascade= {CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REFRESH})
@JoinColumn(name="username")
private InstagramUser user;
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is likely that `InstagramUser.userDetails` is [not *really* lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/how-can-i-make-a-jpa-onetoone-relation-lazy), so the current `UserDetails` also gets loaded into the context, hence the error. <s>Try adding `optional = false` to the mapping to see if the problem goes away.</s>  (See the last paragraph of my answer for why this is not the correct solution)

Alternatively, you can try to reorder your code in the following way:

```
UserDetails merged = userDetailsJpaDao.save(userDetails); // I am assuming userDetails.user is null at this point
instagramUserJpaDao.findById(username)
    .ifPresent(instagramUser -> merged.setUser(instagramUser));
```

Also note that, since in your original code `InstagramUser.user` is the inverse side of the association, the line `user.setUserDetails(userDetails);` really doesn't do anything. You need to populate `UserDetails.user` instead to establish an association between the two entities.