# Issue about JPA One to One Lazy Loading

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I know that lazy loading can't be done if you have a two-way relationship in a one-to-one relationship.

So I read about [How can I make a JPA OneToOne relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/how-can-i-make-a-jpa-onetoone-relation-lazy).

The article says that you can't create a proxy in a one-to-one relationship, but I can't quite understand it.

I think There is no difference between a many-to-one relationship and a one-to-one relationship. He says that in a many-to-one relationship you can create a proxy because you can get the value from FK.

However, one-to-one relationships can also get values ​​with FK, there is no explanation as to why exactly one-to-one relationships can't only get values.

Can someone please explain clearly?

```java
// one to one
class Address {

 ..
 @OnetoOne(fetch = LAZY)
 @JoinColumn(~)
 private Order order;
}

class Order {

 ..
 @OnetoOne(mappedBy = order, fetch = LAZY)
 private Address address; // LAZY not wokring
}
```

```java
// ManyToOne

public class Member {
  @ManyToOne(fetch = LAZY)
  @JoinColmn(~)
  public Team team;  // LAZY working!
}
```

I think these two are different. I know the PK values ​​equally, so why doesn't only the one-to-one relationship do lazy loading?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Address` and `Member` are the same. They own the column representing the association. Let's say, for example, the column `team_id` in the table `Member` and the column `order_id` in the table `Address`.

When Hibernate ORM reads a row from the table `Member`, by checking the value of the `team_id` column, it knows if that value is null or if there is an association. Therefore, when the entity is created it can decide if the value mapping the association (`Mapping#team`)is null or a proxy. In this case lazy fetching is possible.

The table `Order` doesn't have a column representing the association, that's because the association is mapped by the column `order_id` in `Address`. When Hibernate ORM needs to convert a row in the table `Order` to an entity, it also needs to check the table `Address` to see if an association exists. And depending on the result, it will set the value `Order#address` to null or the associated address. In this case, it cannot know if the value of the association is null or not without checking the table `Address`: lazy fetching is not possible.

Note that it might still be possible to lazy fetch the association when the mapping states that the association is never null: `@OneToOne(mappedBy="order", optional=false)`.

Basically, the problem is that if a value can be mapped to null, Hibernate ORM needs to check first if this value is actually null because, otherwise, code like `if (order.address == null) {` is not going to work if a proxy is created.

Empty *-to-many associations are different in this regard because Hibernate ORM maps them with an empty collection (and never with null) and this means that it can always return a proxy.

Comment: Late but I have an additional question.

public class Team {
  @OneToMany(fetch = LAZY)
  @JoinColmn(~)
  public List<Member> members;  // LAZY working!
}

With the example you said, the team also doesn't know the members.
 But here Lazy loading works. What's the difference?

Comment: That's a collection. Hibernate ORM never returns null for collections and therefore can always return a proxy. Basically, the problem happens when a value can be null because if Hibernate ORM returns a proxy, checks like `if (order.address == null) {`  aren't going to work.