# (1+N) selects with OnetoOne associations

Tags: java, performance, hibernate, orm, one-to-one

Considering the following model:

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "USER_ID")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastName;

    @OneToOne
    @PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
    private UserExt userExt;
...     //getters and setters

}

@Entity
public class UserExt {

    @Id
    @Column(name="USER_ID")
    private Long id;

    private String cdpId;

    private Date lastChanged;
...     //getters and setters
}
```

when executing :

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from User");
List<User> list = query.list();
```

Hibernate executes

```
Hibernate: select user0_.USER_ID as USER1_0_, user0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST2_0_, user0_.LAST_NAME as LAST3_0_, user0_.EXT_USERNAME as EXT4_0_ from USER user0_
Hibernate: select userext0_.USER_ID as USER1_1_0_, userext0_.cdpId as cdpId1_0_, userext0_.lastChanged as lastChan3_1_0_ from USER_EXT userext0_ where userext0_.USER_ID=?
Hibernate: select userext0_.USER_ID as USER1_1_0_, userext0_.cdpId as cdpId1_0_, userext0_.lastChanged as lastChan3_1_0_ from USER_EXT userext0_ where userext0_.USER_ID=?
...
...
```

Using a query with specific properties works (select u.firstName, u.userExt.cdpId).

However since I want the full User Entity ("from User"), hibernate generates one select for each result row in the first.

I don't get it since the default fetch strategy should be LAZY not EAGER. Forcing it to LAZY didn't fix the problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are two problems preventing lazy loading here:

1. The default fetch strategy of `OneToOne` is `EAGER` (and keep in mind that `LAZY` is just a hint to the persistence provider).
2. `LAZY` can only work on a `OneToOne` association if the association is non-nullable (at least without using bytecode instrumentation).

> #### 9.1.23 OneToOne Annotation
>
> The `OneToOne` annotation defines a
>   single-valued association to another
>   entity that has one-to-one
>   multiplicity. It is not normally
>   necessary to specify the associated
>   target entity explicitly since it can
>   usually be inferred from the type of
>   the object being referenced.
>
> Table 16 lists the annotation elements
>   that may be specified for a `OneToOne`
>   annotation and their default values.
>
> ```
> @Target({METHOD, FIELD}) @Retention(RUNTIME)
> public @interface OneToOne {
>     Class targetEntity() default void.class;
>     CascadeType[] cascade() default {};
>     FetchType fetch() default EAGER;
>     boolean optional() default true;
>     String mappedBy() default "";
> }
> ```

I tested the following:

```
@OneToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
private UserExt userExt;
```

And confirm that a simple `from User` only loads all the users

```
Hibernate: 
    select 
        user0_.USER_ID as USER1_0_,
        user0_.FIRST_NAME as FIRST2_0_,
        user0_.LAST_NAME as LAST3_0_
    from 
        USER user0_
```

And doesn't perform N additional queries, the `UserExt` are loaded lazily.

So, if you association is mandatory, use the appropriate mapping :) And if it is non-mandatory, you'll have to either:

- use bytecode instrumentation and *no-proxy* fetch (see related question below)
- use a fake ManyToOne instead (didn't test this mapping with a shared primary key)
- eager load the UserExt using a `join fetch` to avoid the N subsequent selects (of course, this somehow defeats the point of a separate table)

Note that Hibernate >= 3.x ignores the Fetch annotation when you use the Query interface. In that case, you need to write that explicitly. this is an example:

```
EntityManager em = [...]
[...]
CriteriaBuilder builder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<User> criteria = builder.createQuery(User.class);

Root<User> usersRoot = criteria.from(User.class);
usersRoot.fetch("Address", JoinType.LEFT);

List<User> users = em.createQuery(criteria).getResultList();
```

#### Related questions

- [OneToOne relationship with shared primary key generates n+1 selects; any workaround?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1002547/onetoone-relationship-with-shared-primary-key-generates-n1-selects-any-workarou/3538465#3538465)
- [Making a OneToOne-relation lazy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444227/making-a-onetoone-relation-lazy)
- [fetchmode in jpa 2 criteriaquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388486/fetchmode-in-jpa-2-criteriaquery)

#### Reference

- JPA 1.0 specification

  - Section 9.1.23 "OneToOne Annotation"

Comment: Congratulations (+1) I have replaced EAGER by LAZY

Comment: Thanks for the complete answer. I will give it a try soon and will let you know the results.

Answer (score 4):

Default fetching strategy when using -ToOne such as @ManyToOne and @OneToOne is **fetch=FetchType.EAGER** NOT *fetch=FetchType.LAZY*

But Hibernate HQL overrides default fetching strategy. If you want to retrieve a fully initialized object by using just one query you must call

```
from 
    User u
 left join fetch 
    u.userExt
```

Answer (score -1):

use optional =true with a one-to-one relationship like this to avoid the n+1 issue with your own Fetch Strategy.

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional=true)
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn
```