# FetchMode in JPA 2 CriteriaQuery

Tags: jpa-2.0

I'm currently in the process of switching from Hibernate to pure JPA 2 (which by the way turned out to be much more time consuming than I initially expected).
The biggest problem I'm having so far is finding a way to force eager loading of lazy properties.
With Hibernate this was done using: `criteria.setFetchMode("person", FetchMode.JOIN);`.
 
Is there any way to do this with JPA 2?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
CriteriaQuery<Person> c = cb.createQuery(Person.class);
Root<Person> person = c.from(Person.class);
person.fetch("address");
c.select(person);
```

Assuming there is a one-to-one relationship between your `Person` entity and an `Address` entity.

Comment: also if you want to retrieve hierachy elements (the root special case) you should have to use a left join like this. 
`CriteriaQuery<JerarquiaOrganizacional> criteria = cb.createQuery(JerarquiaOrganizacional.class); 
Root<JerarquiaOrganizacional> jerarquiaOrg = criteria.from(JerarquiaOrganizacional.class); 
jerarquiaOrg.fetch("jerarquiaOrganizacional", JoinType.LEFT);`