# How to fetch a field lazily with Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, lazy-loading, fetch

Each row of the table `Person` (having `name`, `firstname` and `age`) shall be read.

```
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
Session s = (Session) em.getDelegate();
Criteria criteria = s.createCriteria(Person.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("age", FetchMode.SELECT);
```

But the SQL shows

```
Hibernate:
    select
        person0_.name,
        person0_.firstname,
        person0_.age
    from 
        SCOPE.PERSON person0_
```

How to let the age be lazy **ONLY** for the Criteria??

Comment: I believe thats not possible, but the opposite yes, make it lazy an trigger its initialization when needed.

Comment: In your `Person` entity add to field `age` annotation `@Basic(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)`. At least give a shot.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz I know this style, and i dont like it. It should be part of the criteria, not of the implementation of the Entity.

Comment: What is the sense of not retrieving the age? Less bytes in the wire?

Comment: @gabrielgiussi its because of performance. The age is calculated by timezone, daylight-saving-time, location... let us say, it takes seconds to calculate the age.

Comment: So, if it's calculated what are you persisting in the age field?

Comment: A update-trigger causes a chain of processes... does it realy matter?

Comment: I can't fully understand the requirement behind your question. If the age is calculated with a update-trigger, why it would hurt performance retrieve the age in the query if the saved value is already calculated?

Answer (score 11):

I think that lazy mode only makes sense with associations. If you are accessing a plain table it will load all the fields.

If you want the `age` field not to appear in the SQL and so not being loaded into memory then use projections:

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("name"));
projList.add(Projections.property("firstname"));
crit.setProjection(projList);
```

Comment: Btw: This criteria will produce a List<Object[]> with each Object[] containing 2 Strings for `name` and `firstname`.

Comment: With this approach you should take a look at ResultTransformer.

Answer (score 9):

Setting the FetchMode of the "age" property on a criteria has no effect because the fetching strategy at this point is for associated objects only but not for properties. See section [20.1. Fetching strategies](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching) of the hibernate docs.

> Hibernate uses a fetching strategy to retrieve **associated objects**
>   if the application needs to navigate the association. Fetch strategies
>   can be declared in the O/R mapping metadata, or over-ridden by a
>   particular HQL or Criteria query.

The only way for lazy loading of a property is the `@Basic` annotation set to `FetchType.LAZY`. See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#mapping-declaration-property), or if you use .hbm.xml files for mapping use `lazy=true`, see [this](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch05.html#d5e3233) section of the hibernate docs.

> The @Basic annotation allows you to declare the **fetching strategy for
>   a property**. If set to LAZY, specifies that this property should be
>   fetched lazily when the instance variable is first accessed. It
>   requires build-time bytecode instrumentation, if your classes are not
>   instrumented, property level lazy loading is silently ignored.

Lazy loading of properties also use **buildtime bytecode instumentation** (hibernate is changing the entity classes after compilation to allow lazy loading of properties). Read [20.1.8. Using lazy property fetching](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-lazyproperties)

An other possible solution (except for all the other solutions) to your problem is to make a simpler Person class and use a [constructor query](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch16.html#queryhql-select) like:

```
public class PersonDTO {
    private String name;
    private String firstname;

    private Person(String name, String firstname) {
        this.name = name;
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }
    // getters & setters
}

Query q = session.createQuery("select new your.package.name.PersonDTO("
    + "p.name, p.firstname) from Person p");
q.list();
```

You could even use your existing Person class, just extend it with an appropriate constructor, but I would prefer explicitness.

But all the solutions presented here do not implement a lazy loading of the `age` attribute. The only way to do this is the `@Basic`annotation, or you have to implement your own lazy loading.

Answer (score 4):

Your reasoning is valid (in general; we can however argue about the specific example of the `age` field), but unfortunately there is no straight-forward solution for this. Actually, Hibernate has the concept of [fetch profiles](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-profiles), but it is currently very limited (you can override the default fetch plan/strategy only with the join-style fetch profiles).

So, the possible workaround to your issue could be as follows.

1) Move `age` to a separate entity and associate the `Person` entity with it with a lazy one-to-one relationship:

```
@Entity
class PersonAge {
   private Integer age;
}

@Entity
class Person {
   @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true, optional = false)
   @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_AGE_ID")
   private PersonAge personAge;

   public Integer getAge() {
      return personAge.getAge();
   }

   public void setAge(Integer age) {
      personAge.setAge(age);
   }
}
```

2) Define a fetch profile which overrides the default one:

```
@FetchProfile(name = "person-with-age", fetchOverrides = {
   @FetchProfile.FetchOverride(entity = Person.class, association = "personAge", mode = FetchMode.JOIN)
})
```

3) Enable this profile for *each* session in the application:

```
session.enableFetchProfile("person-with-age");
```

Depending on the framework you use, there should be an easy hook/interceptor which you will use to enable the profile for each session (transaction) that is craeted. For example, an approach in Spring could be to override [AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.doBegin](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.html#doBegin-java.lang.Object-org.springframework.transaction.TransactionDefinition-) of the transaction manager in use.

This way the `personAge` will be eagerly loaded in all the sessions in the application, unless the fetch profile is explicitly disabled.

4) *Disable* the fetch profile in the session in which you use the desired Criteria query:

```
session.disableFetchProfile("person-with-age");
```

This way the default fetch plan/strategy is used (specified in the entity mappings), which is the lazy loading of the `PersonAge`.

Answer (score 4):

If your age is an object like the PersonAge of @Dragan you could associate the fecth mode with the criteria rather than the entity like you do.

So, I think you have three options:

1. age as primitive and projection like @Paco says (Person.age will be null and not a Proxy, you lose the lazyness that you want)
2. age as primitive without projection (more bytes in the wire)
3. age as PersonAge + criteria.setFetchMode (you will get the lazyness that you want at the cost of an extra object/table/mapping)

For Projection you could use ResultTransformer to

```
Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
ProjectionList projList = Projections.projectionList();
projList.add(Projections.property("name"));
projList.add(Projections.property("firstname"));
crit.setProjection(projList);
crit.setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {

      @Override
      public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
        String name = (Long) tuple[0];
        String firstName = (String) tuple[1];
        return new Person(name , firstName);
      }

      @Override
      public List<Reference> transformList(List collection) {
        return collection;
      }
    });
```

I think you could create a PersonProxy on your own that triggers a query for retrieve the age but this is kind of awful.

```
  @Override
  public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
    String name = (Long) tuple[0];
    String firstName = (String) tuple[1];
    return new PersonProxy(name , firstName);
  }

  class PersonProxy {
    Person realPerson;

    public getAge(){
       // create a query with realPerson.id for retrieve the age. 
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can simply define a new entity `SimplePerson` mapped to the same `persons` database table which contains only the following attributes:

- id
- name
- firstName

This way, when selecting a `SimplePerson` with both Criteria and HQL, the age column will not be retrieved.

Another alternative is to use [lazy loading for basic attributes](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-lazy-load-entity-attributes-using-jpa-and-hibernate/), but mapping multiple subentities to the same database table is much more flexible.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add (or maybe clarify) the followings.  Given the main class (Settlement) with an attribute class (Customer):

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "settlement") 
public class Settlement extends IdBasedObject {

...

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id_fk")
    private Customer customer;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "customer", schema = SchemaUtil.SCHEMA_COMMON)
public class Customer extends IdBasedObject {
    @Column(name = "organization_type")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    private CompanyType companyType;

    @Column(name = "organization_legal_name")
    private String companyLegalName;

    ...
}
```

If you would like to get all the distinct customers from the Settlement, you would use the Projections **distinct** on the 'customer' property and followed by creating an alias from the Settlement class:

```
    public List<Customer> findUniqueCustomer() throws Exception {
        Session session = super.getSessionFactory().openSession();

        ProjectionList projectionList = Projections.projectionList();
        projectionList.add(Projections.distinct(Projections.property("customer")));

        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Settlement.class);
        criteria.setProjection(projectionList);
        criteria.createAlias("customer", "customer");

return criteria.list();
}
```

Now, if you do that, you will get back a list of non-proxy error 'could not initialize proxy - no Session' for each of the customer object.

Fortunately, criteria provides the setResultTransformer function that will 're-shape' the return.

```
        criteria.setResultTransformer(new ResultTransformer() {
            
            @Override
            public Object transformTuple(Object[] tuple, String[] aliases) {
                Customer customerObject = (Customer) tuple[0];
                
                Customer customer = new Customer();
                customer.setId(customerObject.getId());
                customer.setVersion(customerObject.getVersion());
                customer.setCompanyType(customerObject.getCompanyType());
                 
             customer.setCompanyLegalName(customerObject.getCompanyLegalName());
             return customer;
             ...
          }

            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            @Override
            public List<Customer> transformList(List collection) {

                return collection;
            }
});
```

The tuple[0] essentially contains the customer object value, since the customer object is not proxied, you will get the error.  In the transformTuple function, you have a chance to 're-create' each of the customer object thereby avoiding the 'non-proxied' error.

Please give a try.

Comment: 1. By nature the same customer can have multiple settlements. 2. One settlement can have multiple customers. 3. In your second code the projectionList is never used so it is a dead object. 4. Since you say that customer to settlement is a 1-1 you do not need a distinct projection. 5. To eager fetch properties throu a resulttransformer have nothing to do with the question "how to fetch lazily". You answer the question "how to fetch eager".

Comment: Hi @Grim. Thanks for pointing out the dead code.  Forgot to include the set projection in the criteria.  Just to clarify, there are many settlements, and they have the same customer. i.e., the same customer make multiple settlements.  The above is to show how do I extract a list of customers from the settlements distinctly.  Yes, you're right, I was trying to show how to fetch a 'lazy' attribute and making it 'eager'.  Cheers.

Comment: At your service. In your class `Settlement` you annotated the property `customer` using the `OneToOne` annotation. But you pointed out that it is a 1-n relation. Then you should use the `ManyToOne`/`OneToMany` annotation instead of `OneToOne` annotation.