# Inverse Relationships, Target Foreign Keys using Mapped By

Tags: jakarta-ee, mapping, jpa-2.1

Two entities has bi-directional OneToOne relationship - [Inverse Relationships.](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToOne#Inverse_Relationships.2C_Target_Foreign_Keys_and_Mapped_By) (as mentioned below) 
I want to lazy load behaviour with "LearnerProfile" while fetching "learner" from DB.
Is this possible, if not, please provide some workaround.

### LearnerProfile.java

```
@OneToOne (fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "LEARNER_ID")
private Learner learner ;
```

### Learner.java

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="learner", fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
private LearnerProfile learnerProfile ;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to load LearnerProfile every time you load Learner, you can use EAGER in `learnerProfile` relationship:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="learner", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private LearnerProfile learnerProfile ;
```

But **I don't recommend** this. The EAGER, one time that exists in your code, it's really [hard to remove](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847289/ignore-a-fetchtype-eager-in-a-relationship) after.

Another strategy is do a JPQL query with `FETCH JOIN`:

```
SELECT l from Learner l FETCH JOIN l.learnerProfile
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use @OneToOne relation (almost always bad design decision). Instead use @Embedded + @Embeddable.