# LazyLoadingException, Hibernate.initialize, FetchMode, MultipleBags

Tags: hibernate

Imagine this relationshipt where a stock has many to many with category.

Stock

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "stock_category" , joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "STOCK_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", 
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Category> getCategories() {
    return this.categories;
}
```

Category

```
 @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "categories")
public List<Stock> getStocks() {
    return this.stocks;
}
```

When I tried to list all categories and your stocks I was getting Lazy Load exception - no session or session was closed.

So I changed my method to initialize all stocks from every category. If I want to initialize another entity I just put it inside for loop:

```
 session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(Category.class)
                     .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);

            List<Category> categories = (List<Category>) cri.list();

            for (Category c :categories) {
                Hibernate.initialize(c.getStocks()); 
            }
```

But I get an SQL for every Category to initialize stocks and I'm thinking this is not good.

So, I tried to use .setFetchMode("stocks", FetchMode.JOIN) and I'll be getting one SQL but if I want use fecthmode and need to join with another entity i'll getting "cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags".

Product

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinTable(name = "product_category" , joinColumns = { 
        @JoinColumn(name = "PRODUCT_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, 
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "CATEGORY_ID", 
                nullable = false, updatable = false) })
public Set<Category> getCategories() {
    return this.categories;
}
```

List:

```
session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(Category.class)
                     .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
                     .setFetchMode("stocks", FetchMode.JOIN)
                     .setFetchMode("products", FetchMode.JOIN);
```

I'm not convinced about which is the best way to do this using hibernate. I read a lot about OpenSessionInView but some suggest that is a bad pattern.

Comment: `but if I want use fecthmode and need to join with another entity`, what do you mean by this, can you add some code and also complete stacktrace of the error so that it is clear to understand

Comment: @user2065083 I mean that if I want do list all categories and categories has tow entites related (stock and product) this error happens! Changed this code to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I understand that your `Category` entity is having `ManyToMany` relationship with entities `Stock` and also `Product`. In your `Category` entity, if you try to use `List` for properties `stocks` amd `products` and then if you want to set the fetch mode to `JOIN` as :

```
`criteria.setFetchMode("stocks", FetchMode.JOIN).setFetchMode("products", FetchMode.JOIN);`
```

then Hibernate throws an exception as:

```
 org.hibernate.loader.MultipleBagFetchException: cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

To fix this issue you have to change the type of properties for `stocks` & `products` to `Set` instead of `List` in your `Category` entity class.

Comment: I modify this and worked. But Which one is the best way to do this? Using Hibernate.initialize or setFetchMode ? is there any other way?

Comment: `setFetchMode` is better compared to `Hibernate.initialize`, because Hibernate issues less number of queries using `setFetchMode`. You can verify that by looking at the queries generated by Hibernate.

Comment: I´m trying to understand pros and cons about solutions. Using setFetchMode bring only the desired data but would be necessary one query for each accessed collection/lazy entity. How it could be made using JPA (because setFetchMode e Hibernate.initialize are hibernate eclusive implementations) ?

Comment: that is a different question and specific to `JPA`, so better ask in a separate post to get correct answers. Also you can refer to this post for more details --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388486/fetchmode-in-jpa-2-criteriaquery