# JPA Query - JOIN Clause

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jpa, hibernate-mapping

I have two tables
**Table A
Table B**

**Table A** contains

Column X
Column Y
Column Z
Column W

**Tables B** Contains

Column P
Column Q
Column R
Column W

**Column W is common in both the tables.**

and their entities

**First Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class TableA extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "X")
    private Long sampleId1;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Y")
    private Long sampleId2;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Z")
    private Date sampleDate3;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = TableB.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "W")
    private TableB tableB;

    ...
    getter
    setter
    ....
}
```

**Second Entity**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TableB")
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class TableB extends AbstractBaseEntity {

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "W")
    private Long sampleId4; 

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "P")
    private Long sampleId1;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "Q")
    private Long sampleId2;

    @Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "R")
    private Long sampleId3;

    ...
    getter
    setter
    ....
}
```

I have an Interface where all the queries are written

```
    Public interface sqlquery{

          String query1 = "from TableA ORDER BY" +
                sampleDate3 asc;";

          String query2= "from TableB";

}
```

Right now i am fetching all data separately in these query, 
I need some help in writing a new single query where data should be shown on the basis of **same ID i.e SampleId4(column W)**
using JOIN clause and where. 
and store the data in result list.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/463349/jpa-eager-fetch-does-not-join

Answer (score 1):

Your mapping doesn't make much sense. If all the columns in table B are part of the ID, that probably means that you might have several rows in it which have the same value in column W. So, if a row in table A has this shared value, it actually references all these rows of table B. So you don't have a ManyToOne association between TableA and TableB.

Regarding your query, since the mapping is wrong in the first place, I don't see how I could write it. End even if it was OK, you should tell us what the query should return, because it's far from being clear.