# Can't fetch certain types of nested objects in Ebean

Tags: orm, playframework, nested, playframework-2.0, ebean

I'm trying to fetch nested objects in Ebean, but it isn't working.  I get the `User`.  It has `Addresses`.  The `Addresses` each have a `House`.  But the `House` only has an `id`.  All other properties are null.  I read on [this other forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ebean/ImsaxdzJsDk/0mKpaExmxj4J) that there may be a bug in Ebean, but it was from 2011.  Is there a way to make this work?

Note: Address and House have a `OneToOne` relationship.

Note: I left out @Entity and @Id for simplicity.

```
public class User {
    @OneToMany
    public List<Address> addresses;

    public static Finder<String, User> find = new Finder(String.class, User.class);

    // This is my query
    public static Event find(Long id) {
        return find.fetch("addresses").fetch("addresses.house").where().eq("id", id).findUnique();
    }
}

public class Address {
    @OneToOne(cascade =  CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "address")
    public House house;
}

public class House {
    @OneToOne
    public Address address;
    public String somePropertyThatIsNullWhenIUseMyQuery;
}
```

Comment: Please try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13011874/why-ebean-returns-null-for-no-reason/13018849#13018849

Comment: Try adding: (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)

Comment: I don't think Ebean supports FetchType

Comment: hmm did not knew that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13171476/eager-fetch-does-not-seem-to-join

Answer (score 1):

```
 Ebean.find(User.class).fetch("addresses.house", new FetchConfig().query())
```

works for me. If you still dont see it, u might want to use

```
 Address.getHouse().getSomeProperty()
```

Sometimes when u just pass the object to JSON f.e. properties shown as null :(