# Difference betwen eager fetching via query/Criteria API and mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, hibernate-mapping

Is there any difference in performance between eager fetching via HQL queries and using FetchType.EAGER as mapping between entities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how your HQL queries are written and how the Eager loading is configured.

See the following question for more information:
[JPA eager fetch does not join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463349/jpa-eager-fetch-does-not-join)