# JPA Repository : inner join with null value

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I am using JPA repository to access Mysql.
I have this query :

```
@Query("Select s.productName, s.stock from Sell s");
```

I am getting an execution error because stock is sometime null.
The generated sql translation of this query is :

```
select sell0_.productName, sell0_.stock_id from T_SELL sell0_ inner join T_STOCK stock0_ on sell0_.stock_id=stock0_.id
```

Is there a way to make this JPA query work even if stock_id is null?

Comment: How have you defined Sell - Stock relation?

Comment: in Sell : @OneToOne
    private Stock stock;

Answer (score 3):

Should be able to coalesce

```
@Query("Select s.productName, coalesce(s.stock,'xxx') from Sell s");
```

Full man is https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/devguide/en-US/html/ch11.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change relation definition, using optional = true:

```
@OneToOne(optional = true)
private Stock stock;
```

You can even change how this data should be fetched, using a join, a subselect or with a different select. More info here: [JPA eager fetch does not join](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/463349/jpa-eager-fetch-does-not-join)